# Range of numbers

Tags: code-golf, number

Came over a similar problem in a project I'm working on and found it quite hard to solve it without excesive use of `if`. I'm eager to see if anyone can come up with more elegant solutions to this, with the aribitary numbers I have given to the line segments.

#### The problem

You are given two integers that act like the end points of a line segment. Determine what existing line segments this line will overlap with.

#### Intervals / line segments

The other lines, named Q, W, E, R and T, are as following:

```
Q:   0 -   7
W:   8 -  18
E:  19 -  32
R:  33 - 135
T: 136 -
```

The last one, T, starts at 136 and has no end point.

#### Example

Given the numbers `5` and `27`, the line will overlapp with `Q`, `W` and `E`. This can be roughly illustrated like this:

```
    Q  W   E       R           T 
---+--+---+-------+-----------+-----
   0  7   18      32         135

     +---------+
     5         27

  (somewhat arbitrary scale)
```

#### Input

Two integers from stdin.

#### Output

A String containing the names of the lines that our new line overlap with, for instance in the example above `QWE`.

#### Rules

Shortest code.

Comment: The numbers `18` and `32` should give `WE` right?

Comment: Do we hard-code the line segments, then?

Comment: @grc: yes. Peter: yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### GolfScript (<strike>43 32</strike> 30 chars)

Contains escape characters. As a hex dump:

```
00000000  7e 29 27 51 08 57 0b 45  0e 52 67 27 32 2f 7b 29  |~)'Q.W.E.Rg'2/{)|
00000010  2a 7d 25 27 54 27 32 24  2a 2b 3c 3e 2e 26        |*}%'T'2$*+<>.&|
```

Base-64 encoded:

```
fiknUQhXC0UOUmcnMi97KSp9JSdUJzIkKis8Pi4m
```

Using bold to indicate escape characters:

```
~)'Q^HW^KE^NRg'2/{)*}%'T'2$*+<>.&
```

Thanks to [Howard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1490/howard) for the suggestion to use escape characters.

Comment: I was just trying this out in the online golfscript tester to see how it worked and kept getting a 'negative argument' error at the `{~*}%` bit. I preceded the code with `5 27`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Gareth, the tester starts with the empty string on the stack from stdin; you need to pop that with `;` and then add the string which you're simulating as coming from stdin. So you need to precede with `;'5 27'` rather than just `5 27`.

Comment: Maybe you can use `'Q\x8W\x0bE\xeRgT\x1c'2/{)*}%` to generate your string? It is -5 chars if you use escapes and even less if you directly encode the values.

Comment: @Howard correct, but the string should be enclosed in double quotes

Comment: @Howard, not quite: the `9$` after `'T'` was to ensure that the string is long enough not to be truncated to the empty string by `<`, so that still needs some special treatment. But otherwise, yes, that works and is useful.

Comment: Great solution! Proof it works: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc1IDI1JwoKfiknUQhXC0UOUmcnMi97KSp9JSdUJzIkKis8Pi4m

Answer (score 9):

### APL (39)

```
'QWERT'/⍨1↓⊃≠/1 0⌽¨0,¨0 7 18 32 135∘<¨⎕
```

Takes input as two whitespace-separated numbers.

Explanation:

- `0 7 18 32 135∘<¨⎕`: For each number in the input, see if 0, 7, 18, 32, and/or 135 is smaller than the number. If the input was `5 27` we now have `(1 0 0 0 0) (1 1 1 0 0)`. (The first one is taken to be the start of the line and the second one the end).
- `1 0⌽¨0,¨`: Prefix a zero to each of those lists and rotate the first one left by 1. (We now have `(1 0 0 0 0 0) (0 1 1 1 0 0)`).
- `≠/`: Gives a list where the individual items of the two input lists were not equal. (We now have `1 1 1 1 0 0`).
- `1↓⊃`: Remove the first item from this list. The other five stand for whether or not to display a Q, W, E, R or T.
- `'QWERT'/⍨`: For each letter, output N of those letters, where N is the corresponding value in the list on the right. Since the list was `1 1 1 0 0` the answer is `QWE`.

Comment: Nice soution and very nice explanation!

Answer (score 6):

### Python <s>82</s> 84

There you are. Edit: Fixed for inputs like `-1 10` and `-10 -1` for 2 chars

```
z=lambda a:(a>7)+(a>18)+(a>32)+(a>135)+1
a,b=input()
print"QWERT"[z(a)-1:z(b)*(b>0)]
```

Answer (score 5):

### J, <strike>58</strike> 54 characters

```
'QWERT '#~0 8 19 33 136 _(([<1{])*(1|.[>:0{]))".1!:1[1
```

Reads one line of input from the keyboard.

Comment: Aargh! Hacky ugly code! ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 79

```
x,y=input()
print"".join(set(("Q"*8+"W"*11+"E"*14+"R"*103)[x:y+1]))+"T"*(y>135)
```

It could be a lot shorter if it's allowed to leave duplicates in the output, but I figured that would be bending the rules a bit.

Comment: How does that handle test case `500 510`?

Comment: Not very well. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Try `-10 1`. It's a pretty box clever answer though.

Answer (score 2):

## K, <strike>68</strike> 58

<strike>`` {$[y>135;`T,;]`Q`W`E`R@&max'(x+!1+y-x)in/:(!8;8+!11;19+!15;33+!104)} ``</strike>

```
{$[y>135;"T",;]"QWER"@&(=).'(y>'0,-1_a),'x<'a:8 19 33 136}
```

.

```
k){$[y>135;"T",;]"QWER"@&(=).'(y>'0,-1_a),'x<'a:8 19 33 136}[5;27]
"QWE"
k){$[y>135;"T",;]"QWER"@&(=).'(y>'0,-1_a),'x<'a:8 19 33 136}[0;139]
"TQWER"
k){$[y>135;"T",;]"QWER"@&(=).'(y>'0,-1_a),'x<'a:8 19 33 136}[20;135]
"ER"
k){$[y>135;"T",;]"QWER"@&(=).'(y>'0,-1_a),'x<'a:8 19 33 136}[32;135]
"ER"
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 159 characters

```
<?$b=array(0=>"Q",8=>"W",19=>"E",33=>"R",136=>"T",1e9=>"");$a=split(" ",fgets(STDIN));foreach($b as $k=>$v){if($a[0]<$k&&$a[1]>=$j)$o.=$p;$p=$v;$j=$k;}echo $o;
```

With line breaks:

```
<?
$b=array(0=>"Q",8=>"W",19=>"E",33=>"R",136=>"T",1e9=>"");
$a=split(" ",fgets(STDIN));
foreach($b as $k=>$v)
{
    if($a[0]<$k&&$a[1]>=$j)
        $o.=$p;
    $p=$v;
    $j=$k;
}
echo $o;
```

Assumes that the line segments are contiguous and non-overlapping as in the given example.

Working version [at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/9D1Ff).

Comment: http://ideone.com/DANYq should output `T`, outputs nothing.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Bugger. I'll have a look.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Added an ugly hacky fix for an extra 8 characters. Maybe I'll stick to J - at least then not many people can understand how hacky and ugly my code is. :-)

Comment: I think `$a[1]>$j` should be `$a[1]>=$j` (i.e. greater OR EQUAL) to correctly hit the edges of each range. e.g. `135 136` should output `RT` but just outputs `R`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala 113

```
val i=Seq(0,8,19,33,136,(1<<31)-1)
i.zip(i.tail)zip("qwert")filter(x=>x._1._2>readInt&&x._1._1<=readInt)map(_._2)
```

Handles test cases 5-27(QWE), 400-500(T), 40-40(R), 33-33(R).

Comment: 400-500 should be T. 40-40 and 33-33 should be R.

Comment: @marinus: You're right. For the R-cases, it was a sloppy testing, but I have to rework the solution to get the case of (400-500) right.

Answer (score 1):

#### M (Micronetics System MUMPS 4.4) - *82 Chars*

```
f i=1:1:2 r a s x=(a>0)+(a>7)+(a>18)+(a>32)+(a>135) w:$d(y) $e("QWERT",y,x) s y=x
```

5-27(QWE), 400-500(T), 40-40(R), 33-33(R).

Answer (score 1):

### PHP 119

```
<?fscanf(STDIN,'%d%d',$a,$b);foreach(array('Q'=>7,'W'=>18,'E'=>32,'R'=>135,'T'=>136)as$x=>$y)echo$y>=$a&&$y<=$b?$x:'';
```

Getting Input from command-line reduces the size, but, I don't think it is applicable here, but still:

### PHP 111

```
<?list(,$a,$b)=$argv;foreach(array('Q'=>7,'W'=>18,'E'=>32,'R'=>135,'T'=>136)as$x=>$y)echo$y>=$a&&$y<=$b?$x:'';
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica

```
Cases[{{q, 0, 7}, {w, 8, 18}, {e, 19, 32}, {r, 33, 135}, {t, 136, \[Infinity]}}, 
  {a_, b_, c_} /; Length@IntervalIntersection[Interval[{b, c}], Interval[{5, 27}]] !=0 
   :> a]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes (improvements wanted!)

```
®Ṁṭ“®¿Çg‘
ØQFḣ5ż¢Œṙ
Ɠ©r/ị¢Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9qZWxsef//wq7huYDhua3igJzCrsK/w4dn4oCYCsOYUUbhuKM1xbzCosWS4bmZCsaTwqlyL@G7i8KiUf//NSwyNw)

```
®Ṁṭ“®¿Çg‘    actual runlengths here
®Ṁ           recall the input numbers, and get the maximum of them
  ṭ          append that max (to be used as runlength for 'T') to...
   “®¿Çg‘    [ 8, 11, 14, 103 ] (listed as base-250 numbers on jelly's codepage)

ØQFḣ5ż¢Œṙ    run-length encoding function:
ØQF          get "QWERTYUIOPASDF..."
   ḣ5        get the first 5 characters of that to yield "QWERT"
     ż¢      zip it with the above link (RLE values)...
       Œṙ    and then apply RLE decode to produce the uncompressed string

Ɠ©r/ị¢Q      main function:
Ɠ©           take two integers from stdin, evaluate them and save them to a register
  r/         take the range between them (technically a fold)
    ị¢       for each element in the range, get the value at its index in the link above...
      Q      and return all the unique values (remove duplicates).
```

I think that I'm doing something wrong / non-optimally with the register save / recall to get the max value. If I just make that value 250, the program goes down to just **22 bytes**:

```
ØQFḣ5ż“®¿Çgż‘Œṙ
Ɠr/ị¢Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjEC3hzsWmx7d86hhzqF1h/Yfbk8HsWccnfRw50yuY5OL9B/u7j60KPD/f1MdI3MA)

Comment: Maybe you can do something like `>“©×þ⁶‘S‘`, i.e. `1+sum(x>i for i in [7,18,32,135])`, and then `ị`ndex into `ØQF¤`. That's [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//PuKAnMKpw5fDvuKBtuKAmFPigJjhu4vDmFFGwqQKxpNyL8OH4oKsUf//NSwyNw). But then inlining the whole thing gets you 20 bytes: `Ɠr/>€“©×þ⁶‘ḅ1‘ịØQF¤Q` using the [ḅ1 trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86253/3852)

Comment: Err, I guess that trick isn't strictly necessary here because it's just as long as `S€` :) but it's good to know about!