# Shortest Konami Code

Tags: code-golf, parsing, keyboard, audio

## The Problem

You must write a program that, when the Konami Code is typed in during runtime, prints the string "`+30 lives`" and sounds a noise of your choice from the computer's speaker.

#### Definition

The "Konami Code" is defined as `UUDDLRLRBA` followed by pressing the enter key.

#### The Rules

- You may choose to use the up arrow for `U`, down for `D`, left for `L`, and right for `R`, as long as your code is consistent with either arrows or letters.
- Your input may be accepted from a controller or a keyboard, but does not need to support both.
- Existing answers may continue to use `BABA` instead of `BA`, but may also shorten it if they wish to do so. Future answers should all use `BA` for consistency.
- Empty input doesn't need to be supported.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73414/discussion-on-question-by-christopher-shortest-konami-code).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 33 bytes (Fine on Empty Input)

```
Dg0Qiq}•ï“ë™µyê!•36BQi7ç“+30™‹“J,
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RGcwUWlxfeKAosOv4oCcw6vihKLCtXnDqiHigKIzNkJRaTfDp-KAnCszMOKEouKAueKAnEos&input=)

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>30</s> 26 bytes (Fails on Empty Input)

-4 thanks to Adnan

```
•ï“ë™µyê!•36BQi7ç,“+30™‹“,
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCiw6_igJzDq-KEosK1ecOqIeKAojM2QlFpN8OnLOKAnCszMOKEouKAueKAnCw&input=VVVERExSTFJCQUJB)

```
•ï“ë™µyê!•36B                  # UUDDLRLRBABA in base-214, converted back to base-36.
             Qi                # If implicit input is equal to...
               7ç,             # Print 7 converted to a character to the console (bell sound)...
                  “+30™‹“, # Print +30 lives.
```

Disclaimer: Bell sound does not play on TryItOnline, maybe ask Dennis if one of his servers somewhere is pinging when you run it.

Comment: You almost won! Just one byte off

Comment: A compressed version of `"+30 lives"` is `“+30™‹“` :)

Comment: This always outputs "+30 lives" for me on the online interpreter, even with empty input.

Comment: @redstarcoder Only* with empty input, crap, fixing

Comment: @carusocomputing can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>202</s> <s>200</s> 198 bytes

Tested only on Chrome and Firefox. Uses `UDLR` rather than the arrow keys. Please make sure that CapsLock is off.

```js
(o=(A=new AudioContext()).createOscillator()).connect(A.destination);s='';document.onkeyup=e=>{(s+=e.key[0]).slice(-11)=='uuddlrlrbaE'&&setTimeout('o.stop()',500,console.log('+30 lives'),o.start())}
```

```html
Please click inside this area to make sure it gets focus.
```

Comment: No need for parens after constructor and move `s=''` to argument of createOscillator. 196: `(o=(A=new AudioContext).createOscillator(s='')).connect(A.destination);document.onkeyup=e=>{(s+=e.key[0]).slice(-11)=='uuddlrlrbaE'&&setTimeout('o.stop()',500,console.log('+30 lives'),o.start())}`

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3,  <s>55</s>  53 bytes

-1 byte thanks to isaacg (use bitwise not to replace `-10` with `~9`).
-1 byte thanks to CalculatorFeline (it is possible to use a literal `BEL` byte).

```python
while'UUDDLRLRBA'!=input()[~9:]:1
print('+30 lives7')
```

where the `7` shown above is a literal byte `0x07` (an unprintable in a code block).

Once enter is pressed the `while` loop condition is checked. If the last `~9` = 10 characters (at most) do not match the Contra command code then the no-op `1` is executed (replacement of `pass` for brevity); if they *do* match then the while loop ends and the `print` statement is executed, which writes the required text along with an ASCII bell character ("alarm"), `0x07`, which produces a sound unless it has been explicitly disabled (or the terminal has no speaker!).

Comment: can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: `-10` = `~9`, which can save you a byte.

Comment: Can't you put a literal \x07 in the string for -1 byte?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I have no idea, can I? Note people often use `\n` in strings in Python golfs, why would they not use `\x0a`?

Comment: *`\a` and it's because you can't have newlines in strings without triplequotes. That only applies to newlines, `BEL`s are fine.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Ah yes true about `\n`. To what does "* `\a` and" refer? When you said "Can't you..." did you mean to say "You can..."? If so, how is a bell written inside a string in one byte of source?

Comment: ...i.e. is [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ13b2EAhJ7MstZhdXfP/fwA) valid?

Comment: Yes (when running from file).

Answer (score 5):

## Processing, <s>161</s> <s>157</s> 155 bytes

```
String k="";void keyTyped(){if(match(k+=key,"uuddlrlrba\\n$")!=null){print("+30 lives");new processing.sound.SoundFile(this,"a.mp3").play();}}void draw(){}
```

The audio file must be saved as `sketchName/data/a.mp3`. Note: I have only tested this program without the audio file because I am too lazy to download an `mp3` file (since only limited extensions are supported from `processing.sound.SoundFile`).

The `draw()` function is needed to be there in order for `keyTyped` to work.

The reason we are using `keyTyped` is because Processing does not have STDIN, it can only listen for keys being pressed via the sketch being run.

#### Explanation

```
String k="";
void keyTyped(){
  if(match(k+=key,"uuddlrlrba\\n$")!=null){
    print("+30 lives");
    new processing.sound.SoundFile(this,"a.mp3").play();
  }
}
void draw(){
}
```

All of the user's keystrokes are stored as chars inside the String `k`. The `keyTyped` is an inbuilt function that is called whenever the user types a key. Simultaneously, we are checking if this String ends with the keystrokes. Then we print `+30 lives` and play the sound file. And the `draw` function is there to continuously update `keyTyped`. After the Konami code is entered, then nothing else will be outputted and no audio will be played.

Comment: it seems like you should count the size of your mp3 file

Comment: @ricyje Processing doesn't really have any other way of outputting sounds. Also, the size of the `.mp3` file doesn't really matter since no matter what it is, Processing will play it as a sound

Comment: @KritixiLithos can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Comment: @ChristopherPeart Done! (I'm glad to save 2 more bytes :)

Answer (score 5):

### Jelly, <s>33</s> <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
ɠ⁻“UUDDLRLRBA”$¿ṛ7Ọ“¡}ʠƈ[ỵ»
```

Turns out, the append (`ṭ`) is not needed, strings are automatically <s>joined together</s> both printed.

```
ɠ⁻“UUDDLRLRBABA”$¿ṛ7Ọṭ“¡}ʠƈ[ỵ»
```

---

**Uncompressed**

```
ɠ⁻“UUDDLRLRBABA”$¿ṛ7Ọṭ“+30 lives”
```

[Try it online](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=yaDigbvigJxVVURETFJMUkJBQkHigJ0kwr_huZs34buM4bmt4oCcKzMwIGxpdmVz4oCd&input=VVVERExSTFJCQUJjCmFzZGYKYnJ0ClVVRERMUkxSQkFCClVVRERMUkxSQkFCQQphc2RmCmtqaGc)
If you remove everything after `¿`, you can mess with the input and see that it only returns when the input string is correct.

```
ɠ⁻“UUDDLRLRBABA”$¿ṛ7Ọṭ“+30 lives” - main link
ɠ                                 - takes a line of input
 ⁻“UUDDLRLRBABA”$                 - $ groups it into a monadic !="UUDDLRLRLRBABA"
                 ¿                - while (the inequality, which takes from the getline)
                  ṛ               - take the right argument (to ignore the input string)
                   7Ọ             - chr(7), the bell character
                     ṭ“+30 lives” - append that bell character to the output
```

Thanks @JonathanAllan for helping me figure out string compression :)

Comment: `“+30 lives”` compressed is `“¡}ʠƈ[ỵ»` (for future reference [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70932/3852) is a post about it, it's linked in the tutorial on the Jelly wiki).

Comment: where is the sound?

Comment: I just tested it with the official interpreter and it [does indeed](http://i.imgur.com/BExqPFJ.png) loop until the Konami code is entered

Comment: @JayDepp can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Comment: I *believe* that it's not so much automatic string concatenation as an implicit print of the LLC (leading constant chain) `7Ọ` followed by an implicit print of the nilad `“¡}ʠƈ[ỵ»`, appearing on stdout as if it were concatenation. As a showcase you can try adding a 2 second sleep between with `ɠ⁻“UUDDLRLRBABA”$¿ṛ7Ọ2“+30 lives”œS`.

Comment: Also I think the code should really be something like `ɠUḣ⁵µ⁻“ABRLRLDDUU”$¿ṛ7Ọ“+30 lives”` so that an entry like `blahblahUUDDLRLRBA` followed by <enter> will also trigger the bell and message.

Comment: @JonathanAllan that's interesting about the printing. At some point I thought about matching the end of the string, but I looked at the other answers and from what I can tell, over half don't do it. I guess that's a result of the vague input specifications.

Answer (score 4):

### ><>, <s>132</s> <s>69</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes <s>[*><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish), 84 bytes</s>

```
i:1+?\0[
:1+?!\i
BA"a~/"UUDDLRLR
{v!?l/!?=
7/"+30 lives"
o<;!?l
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=JYLgjA1A-AOgDAbQFDmgQhsJAhAggIgEMA-AenwFUKARagGQCVGkBvANzSgBtTOBeJAHZyEAMxwABF2BsApgGd8SAPYAeANycuQA)

This relys on the bell chime (ascii `7`) for the noise at the end (not heard on the online interpreter).

Thanks to @TealPelican for saving another 15 bytes!

Saved two bytes checking for `BA` instead of `BABA`.

Comment: Does this make a sound?

Comment: @KritixiLithos, yes you'll see on the second-last line at the very end is a "7", that's the bell chime.

Comment: I've refactored your code a little bit because i didn't quite understand the first lines use? [Try it here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/8FBnKAifK4hmRc4Nr) This link is for ><> but works for *><> too (doesn't use the dive mechanic like you have) - it also saved on 19 bytes! :)

Comment: @Tealpelican, the first line is so it keeps running, waiting for input! Your linked version doesn't do that ;p.

Comment: You are right! I missed that! - I've added a line in to accommodate for my error and replaced some redundant reversing and printing [Try the new version](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/7ZDYzP3RRgrupqRqL) which I've gotten down to 67 bytes :D

Comment: @Tealpelican, almost there! It still exits when it gets the incorrect code, it should loop :p. That's what I had the dive/rise before! It still looks like a serious improvement though.

Comment: I'm sure a lot of the other answers haven't added these restrictions :/ but yes you are correct. This is a super easy fix (lucky!) [V3.0](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/dY22CHmNwxFscczut) 69 bytes - main change added to line 1 ~ becomes >0[ and on line 4 the ; becomes v to redirect back to the new top code.

Comment: @Tealpelican, do they not? Well I'd rather try to keep in the spirit anyways :). It works! I'll make that the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

## C 119 -1 - 2 = 116 bytes

#### Golfed

```
i;f(){char a[14];a[13]=0;while(strcmp(a,"UUDDLRLRBA"))for(i=0;i<12;a[i]=a[i+++1]);a[i]=getch();puts("+30 Lives\a");}
```

#### Ungolfed

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

i;
f()
{
    char a[14];
    a[13]=0;
    while(strcmp(a,"UUDDLRLRBA"))
    {
        for(i=0;i<12;a[i]=a[i+++1]);
        a[i]=getch();
        puts(a); //This is to print every step in the runtime
    }
    puts("+30 Lives\a"); // '\a' is the acsii char that makes sound when passed to STDOUT
}

main()
{
    f();
}
```

Comment: `s/UUDDLRLR BABA/UUDDLRLRBABA` for -1 byte and the strcmp will be looking for the correct string!

Comment: @Christopher please never make edits to people's code on this Stack Exchange site. your edit should never have been approved.

Comment: Mukul, you can remove the space yourself.

Comment: @cat that okay?

Comment: @MukulKumar Of course :) it's important that the answerer edit their own code.

Comment: @MukulKumar can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Comment: @Christopher fixed

Answer (score 3):

## GNU sed, <s>32</s> 25 + 1 = <s>33</s> 26 bytes

+1 byte for `-n` flag.

```
/UUDDLRLRBA$/a+30 Lives\a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f9fPzTUxcUnyCfIyVFFP1Hb2EDBJ7MstTgm8f//tPx8LrgsV1JiEUIpF5BbxfUvv6AkMz@v@L9uHgA)

## Explanation

Every time enter is pressed (`$`), the program checks if the preceding 10 keystrokes were the code. If they were, the `a` command queues the text `+30 Lives` and the bell sound (`\a`) to be printed at the end of the current cycle (which, in this case, is immediately).

Comment: can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Comment: This already has the `BA` just once.

Comment: Oh wow didn't notice

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 50 bytes

```
While[x=!=UUDDLRLRBA,x=Input[]];Beep[];"+30 lives"
```

Initially, `x` is just a symbol and is thus not identical ([`=!=`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnsameQ.html)) to the symbol `UUDDLRLRBA`, so `x=Input[]` is evaluated. This will open a dialog box with the cursor already in the input field, so the user can immediately start typing on the keyboard.

If `Enter` is pressed or `OK` is clicked without typing anything, then `InputField[]` will return `Null`, which is not identical to `UUDDLRLRBA`, so the loop continues and another dialog box will be opened.

If the user clicks `Cancel` or otherwise exits the dialog box, then `InputField` will return `$Canceled`, which is also not identical to `UUDDLRLRBA`, so the loop will continue.

The user can type in the dialog box to their heart's desire. When they hit `Enter`, their input is interpreted as a Wolfram language expression (possibly just boxes). If that expression is anything other than the symbol `UUDDLRLRBA`, the loop will continue.

"Must loop until the Konami code is entered" is a little vague, but I believe this satisfies it. Once the `While` loop is completed, [`Beep[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Beep.html)`;"+30 lives"`.

Comment: can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Comment: `UUDDLRLRB`? Where's `A`?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Fixed

Answer (score 3):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked/), 41 bytes

```
['+30 lives'BEL+out]prompt'UUDDLRLRBA'=if
```

Reads input from keyboard.

```
['+30 lives'BEL+out]prompt'UUDDLRLRBA'=if
[                  ]prompt'UUDDLRLRBA'=if  if the input is the desired string,
 '+30 lives'BEL+out                           output '+30 lives' and the BEL character.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Petit Computer BASIC, 91 bytes

```
@L
WAIT 1S$=S$+CHR$(B)*!!B
B=BTRIG()IF B<1024GOTO@L
IF"xxxxxxxxxx"==S$THEN BEEP?"+30 lives
```

Finally a solution that actually uses controller input!

I used Petit Computer rather than the newer version (SmileBASIC) because it has access to the Start button, and `BTRIG()` is shorter than `BUTTON()`.

I've replaced the data string with `x`'s, it should contain characters with ascii codes 1,1,2,2,4,8,4,8,32,16

#### Boring version, 46 bytes

```
INPUT S$IF"UUDDLRLRBA"==S$THEN BEEP?"+30 lives
```

Comment: I would recommend using **SmileBASIC 2** for the name of Petit Computer entries, and where necessary specify SmileBASIC as **SmileBASIC 3**.

Comment: Nice job using controller!

Answer (score 3):

### AutoHotkey, 63 bytes

```
Input,K,L10
if(K="UUDDLRLRBA"){
MsgBox,"+30 lives" 
SoundBeep
}
```

After running this script, it will check if the next 10 keys are the Konami code and if it is, it will show a message box saying "+30 lives" and it *should* play a beep (I don't have speakers now to test).

Comment: Cool! AutoHotkey is a interesting program.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 21 bytes

```
«_sa}]∷«⇧=`+30 æ§\7`*
```

Based on [@Makonede's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225302/80050).

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%AB_sa%7D%5D%E2%88%B7%C2%AB%E2%87%A7%3D%60%2B30%20%C3%A6%C2%A7%5C7%60*&inputs=UUDDLRLRBA&header=&footer=)

Explained:

```
«_sa}]∷«⇧=`+30 æ§\7`*    
                    *    # Repeat...
          `+30 æ§\7`     # the string '+30 lives␇'... (escape code \7 is BEL)
                         # once if ...
         =               # the (implicit) input equals...
«_sa}]∷«                 # the compressed code...
        ⇧                # in uppercase...
                         # otherwise repeat zero times
```

Comment: `\a` also works instead of `\7`.

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell, <s>89</s> 86 Bytes

```
if((Read-Host)-eq"UUDDLRLRBABA"){"+30 Lives";[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Beep.Play()}
```

enter submits the string to the `Read-Host`, so it should.. work?

Comment: I think you just need to check for "UUDDLRLRBABA" not "UUDDLRLR BABA" as there's no " " in the Contra code. That'd also save you a byte. I think assuming enter because they have to press enter to send the input is valid.

Comment: I does work by the way

Comment: @ChristopherPeart Please don't make edits to others' code even if you are the OP, or if you are saving them a byte.

Comment: Ok I will do that. But It was my fault

Comment: @ConnorLSW can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 50 bytes

```
ol"•";f\@[="UUDDLRLRBA"rl0?ol"+30 lives•"?f0];f0
```

Replace `•` with the character of code `\x07` (the BEL control char). Takes input through STDIN.

Comment: can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Comment: Well I fixed. Thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 2):

## C# (the boring version), 80 bytes

```
void n(){while(Console.ReadLine()!="UUDDLRLRBA"){}Console.Write("+30 Lives\a");}
```

## C# (The interesting one), 202 bytes

```
void n(){t();Console.Write("+30 Lives\a");}void t(){var k="UUDDLRLRBA";var s="";while(s!=k){s+=Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString();s=k.StartsWith(s)?s:"";}if(Console.ReadKey().Key!=ConsoleKey.Enter){t();}}
```

I **think** this works, sadly online testers do not support the existence of a console input, as such I will have to go on the tests I have done

Can most likely be golfed hugely - I'm not great at this! :)

Ungolfed:

```
void n()
{
    t();
    Console.WriteLine("+30 Lives\a");
}

void t()
{
    var k = "UUDDLRLRBA";
    var s = "";
    while(s != k)
    {
        s += Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString();
        s = k.StartsWith(s) ? s : "";
    }
    if(Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        t();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, does C# have a way to read until a newline is detected? That'd save you from looking for the enter key. Look at how it's implemented in Python [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102776/62670).

Comment: There's `Console.Readline` but I thought that might be aganist the spirit of the challenge! If that's fine I can make this much shorter

Comment: @redstarcoder added a `Console.ReadLine()` version

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre can you fix this the BA should only be once (my fault sorry)

Comment: @ChristopherPeart It originally was but I had to change it ;)

Answer (score 1):

### flex, 37 + 5 = 42 bytes

```
%%
UUDDLRLRBA puts("+30 lives\a");
```

The code itself is 37 bytes, compile it with the "-main" option which adds 5 bytes.  Naturally, you have to compile the resulting C file with your favorite C compiler, but I don't think that step should count toward the byte count.

I could save a byte by using a literal BEL character instead of `\a`, but I'd rather be able to read my own code.

Comment: You really don't need to be able to read the code. This is code golf

Comment: Personally, I think I should get a bonus for using flex, due to how rarely it gets used here. :)

Comment: I believe you can reduce the penalty to 3 bytes via giving `-ll` as an option to the C compiler rather than `-main` as an option to flex.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>87</s> <s>85</s> 81 bytes

```
s[13];f(){for(;strcmp(s,"UUDDLRLRBA\n");fgets(s,12,stdin));puts("+30 Lives!\a");}
```

Answer (score 1):

## shortC, 52 bytes

```
s[13];AO;Ms,"UUDDLRLRBA\n");Ys,12,N));J"+30 Lives!\a
```

Explanation:

```
s[13];                                                // declare array with 13 members
      A                                               // main function
       O;Ms,"UUDDLRLRBA\n");                          // for loop while input is not equal to the Konami Code
                            Ys,12,N));                // read 12 characters of input into array
                                      J"+30 Lives!\a  // print the string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v@/ONrQONba0d/at1hHKTTUxcUnyCfIyTEmT0nTOrJYx9BIx09T09pLSdvYQMEnsyy1WDEm8f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 114 bytes

```
#define X "UUDDLRLRBA"
main(i,j){for(i=j=0;!j;)(getchar()==X[i++])&&((j=1?!X[i]|puts("+30 lives\a"):0)|1)||(i=0);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
.•›Gβ…Ýò•uQ7ç“+30™‹ÿ“×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDokcNu9zPbXrUsOzw3MNAalFpoPnh5Y8a5mgbGzxqAcruPLwfyDs8/f//0FAXF58gnyAnRwA)

```
.•...•uQ7ç“...“×  # trimmed program
          “...“   # push "+30 livesÿ"...
                  # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
         ç        # unicode character with codepoint...
        7         # literal...
               ×  # repeated...
       Q          # is...
                  # implicit input...
       Q          # equal to...
.•...•            # "uuddlrlrba"...
      u           # in uppercase...
               ×  # times
                  # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é>Δ┼3Σöîc9qz╔°→cz╣╖↑└
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=823effc533e4948c6339717ac9f81a637ab9b718c0&i=UUDDLRLRBA%0A)

### Explanation

```
`!j.o6F>"`=D"+30 lives"7+
`!j.o6F>"`=               input equals sequence?
           D              if so,
            "+30 lives"   push +30 lives
                       7+ add a bell to it
```