# Shut down the computer!

Tags: code-golf, interactive

### Challenge:

In the programming language of your choice, shut down the machine that your code was executed on.

## Rules

- No shutting down by resource exhaustion (e.g.: forkbomb to force shutdown)
- You are allowed to write code that only works in a specific environment/OS, if you wish.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), thus the lowest amount of bytes wins!

Comment: I got friends, who do this in school and think they are 'hacking' :D

Comment: We should come up with some rule once to stop such `\`whatever\`;` Bash/Perl/PHP/Ruby/etc. stupiglots.

Comment: Full shutdown / Power off @TheBitByte

Comment: Okay, are programs that shutdown after a specific time, and not instantly, allowed? The batch answers shuts down after one minute.

Comment: @TheBitByte as long as the other rules are followed, it's allowed.

Comment: Windows, 0 bytes. Leave the computer on for a few days and let automatic updates do their work

Comment: @LuisMendo automatic updates do not shut down the machine, only restart.

Comment: @briantist  Automatic updates have at times crashed my system, and I have mine set to not restart after a BSOD or other failures.....does that count? :P

Comment: @NZKshatriya the rules say no, it must be powered off  :-p

Comment: Crapola Well, that is one idea out the window.

Comment: @briantist On my computer, restart is shutdown followed by power-on

Comment: Is it acceptable, if the computer shows a confirmation dialog before shutting down but after running the program?

Comment: can the code be a function or does it need to be a programm ?

Comment: Anybody else notice the lack of TIO-links?

Comment: http://notaverb.com/shutdown

Comment: @MontyHarder After reading that page I have decided to coin the term `shatdown: past tense of the verb shutdown`

Comment: @MontyHarder People nowadays will verb almost anything.

Comment: If the [machine catches fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire), does that count as a "shutdown"? ;-P

Comment: Does killing the computer by deleting all the data on it count as a shutdown. ie: running any invalid bash script on suicide linux

Comment: @LuisMendo Depends on your settings really.

Comment: @LliwTelracs Resource exhaustion isnt allowed, and I guess important files for the OS are resources, that you "exhaust" by deleting.. or whatever.

Comment: @P.Ktinos But you are freeing up more space by executing rm -rf /

Comment: **TI-BASIC, 2 bytes**
Note that this only works on an actual TI-84+, not an emulator. Works great on a TI-84+CE with low battery charge.
`:Pause`
Waits for enter keypress. Don't press enter and it will run out of batteries sooner or later.

Comment: On systems that don't support shutdown, such as microcontrollers, can we reset or sleep?

Comment: @steenbergh Had you read the link, you'd see it's not an objection to verbifying other parts of speech. It's about the fact that "shutdown" (as a single word) can't be a verb.  Conjugate the alleged verb. Do I say "Every night before bedtime, steenbegh `shutdowns` the computer?" Would I say "The impasse between President and Congress `shutdowned` the Federal government for three days?"  If you can see that these are wrong, you can see why the correct "phrasal" verb form is "shut down" as two words, not one.

Comment: If the code turns off the machine, it is considered a shutdown?

Comment: @LuisMendo the rule requires the machine to be powered off, so the power on later is not allowed

Comment: I thought about the opposite challenge, "write a code that turn on the computer". But, I guess that beside [wake-on-lan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) and options in BIOS/UEFI, there isn't much options around… (Cf. this question [on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/83685)).

Comment: Just waiting for someone to find a JavaScript exploit for this challenge.

Comment: **PC tower before ATX, 1 keypress**. `On Power buton`!

Comment: @MontyHarder: dead link!

Comment: I was about to answer "`%0|%0` windows batch, 5 bytes" when I saw the rule about resource exhaustion. Bummer.

Comment: Is "melting the CPU" considered to be "resource exhaustion"?

Answer (score 93):

## [Assembly (x86/x64, Linux, as)](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```asm
mov  $0x58,       %al  # 2 bytes: b0 58
mov  $0xfee1dead, %ebx # 5 bytes: bb ad de e1 fe
mov  $0x28121969, %ecx # 5 bytes: b9 69 19 12 28
mov  $0x4321fedc, %edx # 5 bytes: ba dc fe 21 43
int  $0x80             # 2 bytes: cd 80
```

Must be run as root.

**This is equivalent to pressing the power button and not a safe way to power off your PC.** Make sure you close all open applications and execute `sync` to flush all file system buffers before executing this program, to at least minimize the risk of file corruption.

#### Test run

```
$ as -o poweroff.o poweroff.s
$ ld -o poweroff   poweroff.o
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400078
$ sudo sh -c 'sync && ./poweroff'
root's password:
```

Followed by darkness.

#### How it works

`int $0x80` invokes a software interrupt. It works on both x86 and x64, but has been deprecated for over a decade now and should not be used in production code. x64 code should use `syscall` instead. x86 should use `sysenter`, but it is too cumbersome for code golf.

The resulting action from the syscall depends on registers EAX - EDX, ESI, and EDI. The [Linux Syscall Reference](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) shows all syscalls that are available via `int $0x80`.

When EAX holds **0x58 (88)**, *[reboot](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html)* is called, which can also be used to power off, put to sleep, or hibernate the computer, as well as switching kernels and disabling or enabling the **Ctrl - Alt - Del** key combo.

At the start of the program – and by compiling with `as` or `gcc -nostdlib`, we can make sure that we're actually at the start of the program – most registers are set to **0**. This includes EAX, so we can use `mov $0x58, %al` to set the lower 8 bits of EAX to **0x58**, thus setting EAX itself to **0x58**. This saves two bytes over manually zeroing the register with `xor %eax, %eax` and one more over the straighforward `mov $0x58, %eax` which encodes **0x58** in 32 bits.

The first two arguments to *reboot* are magic numbers, presumably to prevent accidental reboots, and are read from registers EBX and ECX. Unless these numbers are equal to certain constants, *reboot* refuses to perform any action.

- The first magic number must equal **0xfee1dead** (*feel dead*), probably referring to the power off / death of the PC.
- The second magic number can be equal to four different constants, although the latter three did not work in ancient versions of Linux. All of them seem to refer to the subsequent power on / birth of the PC.

  - **0x28121969** represents Linus Torvalds's birthday (December 28, 1969).
  - **0x05121996** represents Patricia Torvalds's birthday (December 5, 1996).
  - **0x16041998** represents Daniela Torvalds's birthday (April 16, 1998).
  - **0x20112000** represents Celeste Torvalds's birthday (November 20, 2000).

  Patricia, Daniela, and Celeste Torvalds are Linus Torvalds's three daughters.
- The EDX register selects the type of "reboot" we want. **0x4321fedc** is *RB_POWER_OFF*, shutting the PC down and powering it off.
- Finally, the value of the ESI register is ignored for *RB_POWER_OFF*; the value of the EDI register is ignored entirely by *reboot*.

#### Alternate version, x64-only, 19 bytes

On x64, we can use a proper syscall for the same byte count.

```asm
mov     $0xa9,       %al  # 2 bytes: b0 a9
mov     $0xfee1dead, %edi # 5 bytes: bf ad de e1 fe
mov     $0x28121969, %esi # 5 bytes: be 69 19 12 28
mov     $0x4321fedc, %edx # 5 bytes: ba dc fe 21 43
syscall                   # 2 bytes: 0f 05
```

The only differences lie in the instruction (`syscall` vs `int $0x80`), the value of *__NR_REBOOT* (**0xa9** vs **0x58**), and the involved registers.

Comment: Do we normally count assembly as compiled bytes without the framing bytes required for exe header?

Comment: Yes, because each instruction corresponds to specific bytes in the binary file. ELF files (or whatever format your OS uses) are considered a different language and would have to be created manually to achieve a decent score.

Comment: Could you add the hex dump after assembly of the code?

Comment: @ckjbgames [Here it is.](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#VY7BDoIwEETv/YpJlBsaWsC0HvyXtrs1JmiNEMWvR9AIZbKnmXm7O3jb4YR7fPEjhrBvhW2xi4sR06yhNAOSmuj7MTxDzt4wXOMT2BZ9rXP8lNkG2EDBvTtuj3AFai3@vcAsiS3lyNj1Y6@eew6WQAyWCDwDSkslzcFMgF8DBgcDOY6CWi5UpZKByU8ArQEL8uNuKImqFJdb9wV0gVTJ656gC/EB)

Comment: I `fee1` so `dead` right now.

Answer (score 50):

## PowerShell, 13 bytes

```
Stop-Computer
```

Pretty self-explanatory? Doesn't work on PowerShell core, so it won't work on PowerShell for Linux/MacOS (already tried it on TIO :-D ).

### Bonus Garbage Submission, 12 bytes

```powershell
gcm s*r|iex
```

In my testing, this works on Windows 2003 with PowerShell 2.0. It won't work on most of the newer versions, and it may not work depending on which modules are installed. It's quite terrible!

This searches the list of commands for any with the pattern `s*r` and then runs all of them! To be clear, **this is dangerous, don't do this!**

The trick of course, is getting a list of commands that don't have any mandatory parameters, otherwise PowerShell will prompt for a value.

On my 2003 machine, the 3 commands it returns are:

> ```
> CommandType     Name                                                Definition                                         
> -----------     ----                                                ----------                                         
> Application     scrnsave.scr                                        C:\WINDOWS\system32\scrnsave.scr                   
> Application     ssmarque.scr                                        C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssmarque.scr                   
> Cmdlet          Stop-Computer                                       Stop-Computer [[-ComputerName] <String[]>] [[-Cr...
> ```

Yes, it does launch the marquee screensaver, but no, it does not wait for it to complete before launching `Stop-Computer`.

This approach can work on newer machines, again depending on which modules are installed, but the best I could do on Windows 2012 and 2016 was **14 bytes**:

```powershell
gcm sto*er|iex
```

(and yeah, sure, the winbatch submission will work in PowerShell and it's shorter, but.. that's no fun)

Comment: Shorter one for Win7 & Win10 (and maybe more): `gcm *p-c*|iex` -- and there's only the one result too!

Comment: @Bob highly dependent on installed modules still; on my Win10 machine it returns 6 results, several of which will have mandatory parameters (so they'll prompt and never make it to `Stop-Computer`, which is the last result).

Answer (score 40):

### Batch, 10 bytes

On windows, this would suffice

```
shutdown/s
```

This will set up a shutdown in one minute.

Alternatively, as @flashbang points out:

```
shutdown/p
```

This shuts down the computer immediately.

Comment: `Press the big button on the front of your computer` = 0 bytes

Comment: @RaisingAgent Here at PPCG we solve our problems in code. Physical labour is frowned upon.

Comment: Is it possible for a shorter code to exist written in assembly or parallel language(s) ?

Comment: @steenbergh I don't know... pressing one big button vs 10 keystrokes? I'll go with the button

Comment: @RaisingAgent  Your proposal has scalability issues. Try doing it for 10.000 computers four times a week.

Comment: @RaisingAgent Unfortunately is not always on the front :P

Comment: @RaisingAgent real men use the switch that's right on the PSU

Comment: (smashes computer with sledgehammer)...hunh...puny switch... :-)

Comment: Pretty sure toggling a switch would at least count as 1 bit (or 0.125 bytes, if you prefer)

Comment: @RaisingAgent: and how do you press the big button when the box is on another continent?

Comment: @ccpizza: You use an ICBM. Which, incidentally, *also* includes pressing a big button.

Comment: @Cruncher The one to switch from 230 V to that weird American 120 V? Works once only...

Answer (score 35):

### x86 machine code, Lenovo Z510, DOS COM or Bootloader, 7 bytes

```
BITS 16

mov ax, (1 << 13) | (7 << 10)
mov dx, 1804h
out dx, ax
```

Assembled into `B8 00 3C BA 04 18 EF`

I'm exploiting "*You are allowed to write code that only works in a specific environment/OS, if you wish*" to the ultimate level: this will only work on Lenovo Z510<sup>1</sup>.

This writes `SLP_TYPa << 10 | SLP_EN` to the `PM1a_CNT` ACPI register, I dumped this values from the ACPI tables [months ago for an answer about shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40002262/5801661) (where I give a bit of context to the code above).

This can be run either under DOS as a COM (just write the binary data into a file and change extension to "com") or as a bootloader.
For the latter write the standard signature and [beware of the issues with modern firmware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39248323/5801661).

---

<sup>1</sup> Not strictly true, any system that happens to have the same ACPI configuration will also shutdown.

Comment: Upvoted because of the limited platform.

Comment: Ha! Somebody beat Dennis!

Comment: If you're going with the 7-byte count, you should call this a machine code submission rather than an assembly solution. The assembly submission is 63 bytes.

Comment: @Jakob You are right!

Comment: You look like the right person to answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019463/shutdown-computer-in-ms-dos-using-acpi (I failed miserably at it, had to delete my "answer" out of shame.)

Comment: @Prof.Falken That question is quite old, any particular reason you would like to see it answered? I'm asking just because as it is right now it doesn't seems worth answering unless you can find some value in doing that.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, no, not in particular - just as some kind of hobby. I have a thing for old and weird stuff, and combinations of old and new. DOS + ACPI hits just that note with me. Didn't mean to take your time, have a good day. :-) Looking at it holistically, answering that question may well represent an opportunity cost with a  net negative. I.e. you might have better stuff to do...

Comment: @Prof.Falken More than "better" I'd say *mandatory* stuff do to :P Like everyone else. Well, if I can find the time I'll be glad to answer that question and ping you back :)

Answer (score 34):

## [GRUB shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html), 4 bytes

**Golfed**

```
halt
```

> Command: halt --no-apm
>
> The command halts the computer. If the --no-apm option is specified, no APM BIOS call is performed. Otherwise, the computer is shut down using APM.

**Bonus**

Here is a proof that GRUB shell is indeed Tur**n**ing-complete (see comments):

[image]

Comment: grub shell is not a "programming language" - it's not Turing complete

Comment: @Alnitak really? Even though you can load lua as a module? But note this code also works in bash.

Comment: @Alnitak, what makes you think so ? It features a rather advanced `built-in scripting language, which has a syntax quite similar to that of GNU Bash and other Bourne shell derivatives` and supports variables, conditional constructs, functions and [more](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Shell_002dlike-scripting), so obviously, it _is_ Turning-complete, by any measure.

Comment: OK, I'll take that back - I didn't find that stuff when I looked

Comment: @abligh It doesn't work in bash since the bash version doesn't actually power off the machine without the `-p`

Comment: When it cannot display a spinner it is obviously not Tur**n**ing-complete

Comment: @J_F_B_M ha ha :)

Comment: @J_F_B_M what about those spinners which go like: _  \  | / _  | \ | ... etc

Comment: In Bash it's the same command.

Answer (score 33):

## 65C02 machine code, 1 byte

STP instruction (0xDB):

STP stops the clock input of the 65C02, effectively shutting down the 65C02 until a hardware reset occurs (i.e. the RES pin goes low). This puts the 65C02 into a low power state. This is useful for applications (circuits) that require low power consumption, but STP is rarely seen otherwise.

(Source: http://www.6502.org/tutorials/65c02opcodes.html)

xxd dump:

```
00000000: db                                       .
```

Comment: Noice. I was an Apple II hacker back in the day and didn't even remember this opcode.

Comment: Yeah, after writing a 65c816 emulator with more features and saw this challenge I knew what to do :P

Also, looks like this is the only 1 byte answer so far! \o/

Answer (score 25):

## Matlab, 21 Bytes

```
system('shutdown -s')
```

<s>I haven't tried this (closing all programs to do a restart in the middle of the day isn't really tempting), but it should work.</s>. This works...

I'll add a short explanation later, my laptop is currently off.

Comment: "I'll add a short explanation later, my laptop is currently off." <- The danger of a shutdown challenge

Comment: Axaxaxaxa, well, restarting your computer every once in a while can't be bad :)

Comment: Does ruin your `uptime`, though

Comment: Why submit this as MATLAB, instead of submitting `shutdown -s` as shell?

Comment: Because for me, shell is either something I find on the beach, or a gas station.

Answer (score 21):

## MATLAB, 11 bytes

```
!shutdown/p
```

Somewhat similar to [Stewie Griffin's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107878/32352). However, MATLAB has ***way*** shorter ways of invoking system commands; in this case, `!` is used. Windows does not need `.exe` for command names, so that's left out as well. The `/` option is still supported (I'm running Windows 10), and negates the need for the space. Alternatives are:

```
system shutdown/p % 17 bytes; uses so-called 'command' syntax.
dos shutdown/p    % 14 bytes; the 'dos' command can be used just as well.
```

Answer (score 19):

## SmileBASIC, <s>14</s> <s>11</s> 6 bytes

```
OPTION
```

Triggers a crash causing the 3DS to restart.
I hope this counts.

Works in the most recent version.

Comment: I thought this had been patched... Please include a version number.

Comment: It has been patched in version 3.5, which hasn't been released outside of Japan yet.

Comment: @12Me21 Sure it counts. Nice choice of environment.

Comment: If only `REBOOT` from SBv2 counted as a valid answer.

Answer (score 16):

## Bash, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
init 0
```

Assuming that the program is run as root.

Comment: Indeed, powering off the machine is required. Thus you need 'halt -p' as a valid answer

Comment: This editing massacre :)

Comment: @P.Ktinos: `poweroff` is a single word, although slightly more letters.

Comment: @ccpizza Right, but the typical scoring criteria is [byte count](https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-to-count-bytes-faq)

Comment: Also, `init 6` would restart the machine, but not sure that would completely count as "turning off."

Answer (score 14):

## Python 2, 29 bytes

```python
import os;os.system('init 0')
```

Works on Linux systems and needs root privileges.

**For Windows, 33 bytes**

```python
import os;os.system('shutdown/p')
```

Comment: Someone else [posted](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107879/14446) the Linux shell version.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad..

Answer (score 14):

## Commodore 64, 11 bytes

```
0 sys64738
```

This is from the BASIC prompt. Or...

#### Commodore 64, 6502 assembly, 3 bytes (assembled), 16 bytes (source)

```
*=8000
JMP $FCE2
```

Comment: I think that using the Commodore 64's direct input mode from BASIC with `sys64738` will use _zero bytes_ as there is no program or anything else to store; You are using screen RAM but that RAM will already be filled with spaces, so you're just replacing those spaces with text.

Comment: The source code takes up space. Just because it doesn't _reserve_ space _on the target machine_ doesn't mean it takes up 0 bytes. Otherwise the answer would be ``.

Comment: I agree with @wizzwizz4 but even with the line number and space isn't your submission 10 bytes? Or are you counting the newline too?

Comment: You don't need the space between the `0` and the `sys64738`, you can replace the `sys` with the shortcut form `sY`, and I don't count the trailing newline in program length.  However, I don't think your code meets the requirements: the code at 64738 does a soft reset, not a poweroff.

Comment: I used the PRINT FRE() function to determine the number of bytes used. Even if I obfuscate the BASIC 2.0 keywords, the FRE() function will still return the same number of bytes, and missing out the space between the 0 and the keyword will still produce the same result as Commodore BASIC adds in a space after the line number for presentation purposes.

Comment: Does not power off.

Comment: I once spilled beer on my Commodore 64, that powered it off permanently. Does this count?

Answer (score 13):

## Java, <strike>101</strike> <strike>98</strike> <strike>62</strike> 42 bytes

```
()->{Runtime.getRuntime().exec("init 0");}
```

As @Snowman pointed out, the question didn't specify if a full program was needed, so this should still be acceptable.

Comment: It's shorter to replace `class` with `interface` as that allows you to omit `public` from main.

Comment: You can use a method, since the question did not specify the submission must be a full program: `void f()throws Exception{Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown/s");}`

Comment: Wouldn't the [Linux version](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107879/14446) be a bit shorter?

Comment: `()->{Runtime.getRuntime().exec("init 0");}` or tentatively `()->Runtime.getRuntime().exec("init 0")` (can't check at the moment). It's a lambda implementing a custom void, no-args-throwing interface.

Comment: This should be labeled as a Linux-specific answer, e.g. "Java on LInux".

Answer (score 12):

## C++, <strike>51</strike> 40 bytes

-11 bytes thanks to [Ingve](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64901/ingve)!

```
#include<os>
int main(){OS::shutdown();}
```

Only works in [IncludeOS](http://www.includeos.org/) (v0.10.0-rc.1)

Test:

```
$ pwd
/home/simon/IncludeOS/examples/demo_service

$ cat service.cpp
#include<os>
int main(){OS::shutdown();}

$ mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make && cd ..
[...]

$ boot build/IncludeOS_example
[...]
================================================================================
================================================================================
 IncludeOS v0.10.0-rc.1-9-g151a2b9
 +--> Running [ IncludeOS minimal example ]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

$
```

Comment: Now i am curious about IncludeOS

Comment: @KarlNapf Alfred held a great presentation at CppCon 2016 about IncludeOS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4etEwG2_LY if you want to know more :-)

Comment: You don't need to use `void Service::start`, `int main` [works in IncludeOS](https://github.com/hioa-cs/IncludeOS/blob/dev/test/posix/integration/main/service.cpp) as well.

Answer (score 12):

## AppleScript, 30 bytes

```
tell app "Finder" to shut down
```

Does exactly what it says: tells Finder to shut the computer off.

Answer (score 12):

### TI-Nspire CX CAS, 3 bytes

```
" "+" "
```

*summing two empty strings.*

On an older version of the calculator, this would crash the device and cause it to reboot (there's no way to shutdown a device without reboot apart from physical button combinations).

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvxFxzDgS2U) by Adriweb

Comment: Isn't that 7 bytes?

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4764/62824 @RomanGräf

Comment: Sounds convincing to me.

Answer (score 10):

## AutoHotkey, <s>11</s> 10 Bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to [Gurupad Mamadapur](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47650/gurupad-mamadapur)*

```ahk
Shutdown,9
```

AHK Supports a Shutdown command by default. The `9` is a flag, consisting of `Shutdown=1` + `PowerDown=8`.

Comment: `AHK` is mysterious.

Comment: Do you need the space after the comma?

Comment: space after `,` is not needed. Try testing it with a different flag. 

I thought this will not immediately shut down the computer, and put it in my main script which loads at startup :D Now I've to load in safe mode and solve the problem. Sigh.

Answer (score 10):

## Machine code (x86, boot loader) 18 bytes

```
b8 01 53 33 db cd 15 b8 07 53 bb 01 00 b9 03 00 cd 15
```

Disassembly:

```
mov ax, 0x5301 ; connect to real-mode APM services
xor bx, bx     ; device id 0 - APM BIOS
int 0x15       ; call APM
mov ax, 0x5307 ; set power state
mov bx, 0x0001 ; on all devices
mov cx, 0x0003 ; to Off
int 0x15       ; call APM
```

You can test it in Bochs' debugger with the following commands (after starting simulation, having some disk drive set up):

```
pb 0x7c00
c
setpmem 0x7c00 4 0x335301b8
setpmem 0x7c04 4 0xb815cddb
setpmem 0x7c08 4 0x01bb5307
setpmem 0x7c0c 4 0x0003b900
setpmem 0x7c10 2 0x15cd
c
```

This same machine code will also work as a DOS executable (`*.COM`).

Answer (score 8):

### C#, <strike>79</strike> <strike>54</strike> 53 bytes

This works on Windows.

**79 bytes**:

```
class _{static void Main(){System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown","/s");}}
```

**53 bytes**, thanks to TheLethalCoder:

```
_=>System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown","/s");
```

Comment: Note the challenge doesn't require a full program and doesn't disallow taking an input (unused of course) so you could compile to an `Action<int>` and do `_=>System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s");` for 54 bytes.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, updated, thanks!

Comment: You can also remove the unnecessary space.

Comment: Of course yes! Thank you, @nothrow :)

Answer (score 6):

## AutoIt, 11 bytes

```
Shutdown(1)
```

Shutdown function gets combination of following codes

```
0 = Logoff
1 = Shutdown
2 = Reboot
4 = Force
8 = Power down
16= Force if hung
32= Standby
64= Hibernate
```

To shutdown and power down, for example, the code would be 9 (shutdown + power down = 1 + 8 = 9).

Comment: `0` (logoff) is a special case here; it does not combine with Standby or Hibernate implicitly.

Comment: OK `0 + 32 = 32`

Comment: Hm, so does it always log off before going to standby/hibernation?

Comment: @Ruslan I do not  know exactly  how it works, You can refer to [AutoIt user forum](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum) to receive more feedbacks:-)

Answer (score 6):

## Windows - NativeAPI, 212 bytes

Ok this is not really the shortest version.
But maybe interesting to some.
This will *not* execute on the Win32 subsystem. However it will run when executed within the context of the native api (like autochk.exe does)

## Code

```
#define WIN32_NO_STATUS
#include <windef.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <ntndk.h>
NTSTATUS main() {
RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_SHUTDOWN_PRIVILEGE,TRUE,FALSE,NULL);
return ZwShutdownSystem(ShutdownPowerOff);
}
```

## Build

To build this either use the WinDDK `build.exe` tool (with an appropriate `source` file for `NMAKE`)

Or use these commands to compile and link:

```
cl /Gd /D_X86_ /showIncludes /I%DDK_INC_PATH% /I%CRT_INC_PATH% /c main.c
link /verbose /nodefaultlib /subsystem:native /machine:X86 /entry:NtProcessStartup@4 C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\i386\nt.lib C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\i386\ntdllp.lib C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\i386\BufferOverflow.lib .\main.obj
```

Note: This will build an x86 native executable. Change the appropriate bits if you want to build this for a different architecture.

## Test

To test a native executable you have to execute it **before** the win32 subsystem is loaded. One common way to do it is to append the executable in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute
```

## Warning

If you do this however, you need to have an option to edit the registry hive of the target OS from another OS. Since **you will not be able to boot the target OS anymore!**

I did it on a VM where i could easily revert to a previous snapshot!

Answer (score 5):

### Groovy, 23 bytes

```groovy
'shutdown /p'.execute()
```

Comment: Is the space before the slash necessary?

Comment: @steenbergh Yes, it is needed.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur are you sure?

Answer (score 5):

## J, 14 bytes

```
2!:0'poweroff'
```

Works on Linux systems. `2!:0` executes the string in `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 5):

### AppleScript, 44 bytes

```
tell application "Finder"
shut down
end tell
```

I don't know how AppleScript syntax works or anything, so if anybody knows how to shorten this, please tell.

Also, I'm doing this on my phone at school ("hacking"), so I can't test it.

At 14 fewer bytes (thanks to kindall) you can say

```
tell app "Finder" to shut down
```

Comment: Someone came up with a shorter solution (with same program) a few hours after you (but posted it instead of commenting here) http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107958/62824

Comment: You can probably remove the indentation

Comment: `tell app "Finder" to shut down` should work, I believe (though the compilation may replace 'app' with 'application').

Answer (score 5):

## Most Linux shells, 15 bytes

```
# echo o>/p*/*ger
```

It could be made to be 11 bytes long, if you happen to be in the `/proc` directory:

```
# echo o>*ger
```

This is very straightforward (has no side effects, like unmounting filesystems or killing processes) and rather brutal.

Comment: Last time I tried wildcard expansion on redirect it generated a file with the wildcard in it despite a matching file existing.

Comment: I believe you have to add "/proc/" to your byte count

Comment: @Joshua It might be shell dependent. I actually tested it (with `bash`) on my computer :-)

Comment: @zeppelin Not if you are already in the directory. For all we know, it might be your $HOME - unusual, but not impossible...

Comment: @Radovan Garabík - I don't think that is really valid. This is basically the same as implying that there is an alias "p=poweroff" (which is not "impossible" too) and claiming "p" to be a valid _1 byte_ solution.

Comment: But you can probably make it valid at expense of just 3 bytes, like this `echo o>/p*/*ger`

Comment: @zeppelin True. Anyway, going for the shortest command was not my primary goal. My goal was to have a command that does what has been asked, nothing more - other answers have the OS perform various side effects, like killing processes or umounting filesystems :-)

Answer (score 5):

### Android shell, 9 bytes

```
reboot -p
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 4):

## Clojure, <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```clj
(.exec(Runtime/getRuntime)"shutdown/s")
```

-1 byte by changing the flag from `-s` to `/s`, which allowed me to get rid of the space.

Basically the Java answer.

Testing this was fun. Windows decided to do a firmware update on my Surface the second it shut down. Of course.

```clj
(defn shutdown []
  (.exec (Runtime/getRuntime) "shutdown -s"))
```

Answer (score 2):

### C++,  <s>48</s> 47 (Windows)  <s>46</s> 45 (Linux) bytes

Removed 1 byte thanks to Snowman

```
#include<cstdlib>
main(){system("shutdown/p");}
```

This should shutdown the system for windows

```
#include<cstdlib>
main(){system("poweroff");}
```

This should shutdown the system for Linux

Comment: do you need the `;`?

Comment: @LliwTelracs Pretty sure it is "shutdown /p" and not "-p" and the space is not needed.

Comment: The semicolon is required for proper c++ syntax, using a slash allows for a shorter answer for windows but makes it no longer work for linux. Although I added the wrong character for shutdown that is shared between windows and linux

Comment: @LliwTelracs Although you can do whatever you want, I suggest abusing the 2nd rule and not caring about Linux functionality, since this is a code-golf and low amount of bytes is better.

Comment: I separated it into windows and linux power off

Comment: @P.Ktinos `shutdown /p` and `shutdown -p` are the same thing

Comment: @TrojanByAccident What he meant is that i could remove the space if i used slash for on windows, which removed 1 byte

Comment: `#include<cstdlib>` will shave off a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Node.js, 39 bytes

Linux

```
require('child_process').exec('init 0')
```

Answer (score 2):

### Bash 15 bytes

```
shutdown -h now
```

alternatively : `init 0`

Comment: useless use of `sudo`

Comment: you're right given that only one user is logged in! :)

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica on Windows 16 Bytes

Invoke the shell command with Run.

```
Run@"Shutdown/p"
```

Comment: Does this work on every OS, or a specific one?

Comment: @GregMartin Windows only.  Maybe a Linux guy can comment on modifying this to pass the appropriate shell command there.

Comment: I'm sure a Linux person of any gender could! Perhaps "Mathematica on Windows" is more precise in the post itself?

Comment: Lol. I use "guy" in the gender-neutral sense. http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2016/02/10/the_gender_neutral_use_of_guys_is_on_the_rise_but_it_s_a_slow_rise.html

Comment: Although this term is still being debated, it is certainly the case that "guys" is not uniformly gender-neutral; and research definitely shows that gendered language has a harmful effect on STEM disciplines and the women participating in them. I believe it's important to bend over backwards to be inclusive with our language, since the gender equity problem is not solving itself.

Comment: Linux shutdown code: `shutdown +0` is the traditional way to do a shutdown and power off (using the tersest representations of the flags); `shutdown` with no arguments will delay 60 seconds then shut down. On recent systemd-based systems you're supposed to use `systemctl halt` or `systemctl poweroff` instead, but that's more bytes so who cares about that. Note that any of these commands require root permissions (as shutting down the system could cause data loss for anyone else logged in at the time, it's an action that affects other users, so you need enough permissions to be able to do that).

Answer (score 2):

### AHK, <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```ahk
Run,Shutdown -s
```

Works on windows only.

Answer (score 2):

### R, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
shell("shutdown/s")
```

---

Previous answer :

```
system("shutdown/s")
```

Comment: `shell("shutdown/s")`? (19 bytes)

Comment: @djhurio well done ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 3 bytes

```
ClrHome:"
```

Basically, this displays a blank screen and then waits for automatic timeout to kick in and shutdown the calculator, although you will not notice when this happens. The blank screen resembles a shutdown so you will not notice when the device actually shuts down.

Answer (score 2):

## **PHP, 20 bytes**

```
shell_exec("init 0");
```

Answer (score 2):

### DOS 7.1 (Windows 98) command prompt/batch, 5

```
WIN/P
```

Only works from real mode (MS-DOS command prompt).

Comment: Isn't the switch for *soft*-power-off `/Z`?

Comment: Might be. It's been a long time.

Answer (score 2):

## Assembly (Z80, Amstrad CPC), one byte

Amstrad CPC cannot be physically shut down by software, but system can be reset.

The following one-byte assembly program is enough to reset system:

```
C7    ;RST 0
```

It is a valid assembly program (in RAM) since no header of any kind is needed on this system.

You can install this program from BASIC e.g.:

```
poke 999,&c7
```

Then call it:

```
call 999
```

### Can I haz test?

You can test at once on [CPCBox - Amstrad CPC emulator in Javascript](http://www.cpcbox.com/).

Comment: If using keypresses as a metric instead of program bytes, see this other answer for a shorter variant: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108248/38578

Answer (score 2):

## Lisp, 38 bytes

```
(trivial-shell:shell-command "init 0")
```

Comment: Which dialect of Lisp does this work in?

Answer (score 2):

#### Alternative Python on Linux + SysRQ, <strike>47</strike> 42 bytes:

```
open("/proc/sysrq-trigger","w").write("o")
```

Can be  run either from `python -c` or from script, and requires root privileges to write to the file. The idea isn't python-specific. Writing to that file on Linux can be done in any other way - bash, perl, ruby , etc.

Note that this isn't a graceful shutdown, so expect that there is potential for data to be lost. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) for more info on sysrq keys.

Comment: `open("/proc/sysrq-trigger","w").write("o")` saves a few bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## **[EthOS](http://ethosdistro.com/) Shell - 1 byte**

Just type the letter `r` to reboot, i.e.:

`r`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 53 bytes

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s"])
```

This does give a window and shutdown warning.  If you wanted to shut it down immediately then you would use "/p".

You could also call the function from the USER library but this is a longer solution than the submitted version.

Comment: Would `os.system('shutdown\s')` not work? I don't want to try it right now in case it does work :)

Comment: @Farhan.K No. It tries to find `s` inside the `shutdown` directory. (Windows 10)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Sorry I meant `os.system('shutdown/s')`

Answer (score 1):

## JScript, 53 bytes

```js
new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell').Run("shutdown /s")
```

JScript is Microsoft's implementation of JavaScript. Run with `wscript scriptname.js`.

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript, 46 bytes

```js
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "shutdown /s"
```

Run with `wscript scriptname.js`.

Answer (score 1):

## Amstrad CPC Basic, 7 keypresses.

Amstrad CPC cannot be physically shut down by software, but system can be reset with this BASIC call:

```
call 0
```

### How it works

#### General info

At the beginning of memory (either RAM or ROM, both are prepared for this), there is a table for Z80 `RST` instruction. These instructions, related to Z80 interrupt handling, are also used (even on machines other than Amstrad CPC, like [TI-81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-81)) for other tricks because one-byte long assembly instruction is enough to reach any of the 8 entries.

On the Amstrad CPC they are used to space-efficiently call code in ROM, RAM, expansion RAM/ROM, see [BIOS Function Summary - CPCWiki](http://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php/BIOS_Function_Summary) or [ref page 8+](http://www.cantrell.org.uk/david/tech/cpc/cpc-firmware/firmware.pdf).  This is used extensively to make RAM-based indirections that allow easily calling ROM routines from RAM (even from BASIC, like `call &bd19` that waits for screen refresh) and also, by changing them, modifying system behavior even though system is in ROM (like changing how text is displayed, or even redirecting it to printer by changing two bytes of RAM). See `BB00` and following in [BIOS Function Summary - CPCWiki](http://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php/BIOS_Function_Summary) or [Firmware Guide](http://www.cpcwiki.eu/imgs/e/e1/The_Amstrad_CPC_Firmware_Guide.txt)

#### Specific use

Entry zero jumps to a ROM-base routine that performs full machine reset.  The simplest way to call it from BASIC it `call 0`.

### Variant

If you insist on a program that can be run rather than a direct command, it takes 8 keypresses:

```
1call 0
```

Then you can `run`.

### Can I haz test?

You can test at once on [CPCBox - Amstrad CPC emulator in Javascript](http://www.cpcbox.com/).

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore 128 (from native mode), 6 characters including user response and return

```
GO64
```

You will then be prompted with:

```
ARE YOU SURE?
```

Press Y and enter. This shuts down the C128 native mode (I know it doesn't power off the computer, but that's as close as I can get).

Answer (score 1):

## Machine code (x86 boot loader), 2 bytes

```
fa f4
```

Disassembly

```
cli ; disable all maskable interrupts
hlt ; stop the processor until an interrupt or hard reset happens
```

The HLT instruction causes the CPU to stop execution and enter low-power mode, until any interrupt (maskable or NMI) or hard reset happens. This doesn't power off the whole system, but the original IBM PC didn't have any way to power off without the user mechanically pressing the switch. Also, if there happens an NMI, and its handler returns, the program will resume and execute arbitrary code which happens after `f4`. This is unlikely though, since NMI usually signals about hardware faults.

This same code will work as a DOS `.COM` program.

Comment: IIRC, this could be used to hang Win9x, where the DOS box had an IOPL of 3

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5 (on a unix-like OS), 6 bytes

```
`halt`
```

Requires you to be root.

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 25 bytes

It makes use of the undocumented monad `ŒV`, which takes a list, concatenates it and evaluates it using Python's `eval`.

```
“WƒuUḤøMŒƁEḄV#ẆṄⱮṁƬṅȯV»ŒV
```

The compressed string translates to `import os;os.system("poweroff")` so it only works on Linux (with root). The following code was used for [compressing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70932/63647).

```
Compress().dictionary('import')
          .string(' os;os.')
          .dictionary('system')
          .string('("')
          .dictionary('power')
          .dictionary('off')
          .string('")').go()
```

By changing the `poweroff` it can be extended to other systems (but `power` and `off` are in the dictionary so this will probably be the shortest). For example, following 33-byte version worked on a Mac.

```
“¡Ṁ\\meṾṭ£ȧ+⁾⁸}ḶṠȯƇọṣỴ\\Ḃ⁴8ġṢṾ»ŒV
```

Answer (score 1):

## shortC, 10 bytes

```
A$shutdown
```

Explanation/ungolfed:

```
A           main function
 $          execute system command
  shutdown  shutdown
```

Answer (score 1):

### AppleScript (45 bytes)

```
tell application "System Events" to shut down
```

Comment: That's considerably more verbose than telling `app "Finder"` to shut down.

Answer (score 1):

### Vimscript (Linux Bash) 8 bytes

```
:!init 0
```

### Vimscript (Windows CMD) 12 bytes

```
:!shutdown/p
```

### Vimscript (Windows PowerShell) 15 bytes

```
:!Stop-Computer
```

Two dots `:` are required for the vim command, and the '!' redirects the command to the shell runing behind. You may require some extra permissions for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Thumb machine code, Nintendo DS,  30 bytes

```
05 48 05 49 00 23 02 88 12 0a fc d2 01 80 43 80
09 0c 40 23 f7 e7 c0 01 00 04 02 88 02 80
```

Thumb function. Runs at an address that is 2 byte aligned, 4 byte unaligned, **on the ARM7.** The ARM9 cannot access these registers.

This version follows the spec by writing the two halfwords separately, like the [code in libnds](https://github.com/devkitPro/libnds/blob/7e8902ac2a9ae3a983fa0519b4f7026d04d7d0fd/source/arm7/spi.c#L31). Known to work on DeSuMME (it will log it in the console menu) and melonDS, and should work on hardware.

Assembler source:

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv4t
    .thumb

    // Force misalignment to align PC load
    // Not part of function
    .p2align 2,0
    .hword 0
    // Begin code
    // void shutdown(void);
    .thumb_func
    .globl shutdown     
shutdown:
    // Load address of SPI register
    ldr     r0, REG_SPICNT
    // Load packed SPI commands
    ldr     r1, SPI_COMMANDS
    // Set SPIDATA to select PM_CONTROL_REG
    movs    r3, #0x00
.Lloop:
    // Wait for REG_SPICNT & SPI_BUSY to clear
    ldrh    r2, [r0]
    // Test bit 7 by shifting into carry flag
    lsrs    r2, r2, #8
    bcs     .Lloop
    // Store the low 16 bits of the command to REG_SPICNT
    strh    r1, [r0]
    // Store data to REG_SPIDATA
    strh    r3, [r0, #2]
    // Shift in the next SPI command
    lsrs    r1, r1, #16
    // Set SPIDATA to PM_SYSTEM_PWR
    movs    r3, #0x40
    // Run again with the new commands
    // Then spin again until the SPI powers off the system.
    b       .Lloop

REG_SPICNT:
    // Address of ARM7 IO register
    .word   0x040001c0
    // Two packed halfwords
SPI_COMMANDS:
    // Start a command on the Power Management device,
    // read a byte to select the register
    // SPI_ENABLE | SPI_BAUD_1MHz | SPI_BYTE_MODE | SPI_CONTINUOUS | SPI_DEVICE_POWER
    .hword  0x8802
    // Finish the command on the Power Management device,
    // read a byte to run the action.
    // SPI_ENABLE | SPI_BAUD_1MHz | SPI_BYTE_MODE | SPI_DEVICE_POWER
    .hword  0x8002
```

---

## ARM Thumb machine code function, Nintendo DS, unsafe, 28 bytes

```
03 48 04 49 02 88 12 0a fc d2 01 60 02 49 f9 e7 
c0 01 00 04 02 88 00 00 02 80 40 00
```

This function runs at a 4 byte aligned address on the ARM7.

This cheats 2 bytes by writing to SPICNT and SPIDATA at the same time in a full word write, something that has not yet been confirmed to work on hardware. It does not work on DeSuMME, but this might just be an emulator bug.

I am including this because it uses different code.

Assembler source:

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv4t
    .thumb

    // Force 4 byte alignment
    .p2align 2,0
    // Begin code
    .thumb_func
    .globl shutdown
shutdown:
    // address of SPI register
    ldr     r0, REG_SPICNT
    // Set SPI register bank
    ldr     r1, SPI_SELECT_PM_CONTROL_REG
.Lloop:
    // Wait for REG_SPICNT & SPI_BUSY to clear
    ldrh    r2, [r0]
    // Test bit 7 by shifting into carry flag
    lsrs    r2, #8
    bcs     .Lloop
    // Store to both SPICNT and SPIDATA
    str     r1, [r0]
    // Send SPI command
    ldr     r1, SPI_SEND_PM_SYSTEM_PWR
    // Loop again with the new value.
    b       .Lloop
    .p2align 2,0
REG_SPICNT:
    .word   0x040001c0
    // SPICNT = SPI_ENABLE | SPI_CONTINUOUS | SPI_BAUD_1MHz | SPI_DEVICE_POWER
    // SPIDATA = PM_CONTROL_REG
SPI_SELECT_PM_CONTROL_REG:
    // Combined halfwords
    .hword  0x8802
    .hword  0x0000
    // SPICNT = SPI_ENABLE | SPI_BAUD_1MHz | SPI_DEVICE_POWER
    // SPIDATA = PM_SYSTEM_PWR
SPI_SEND_PM_SYSTEM_PWR:
    // Combined halfwords
    .hword  0x8002
    .hword  0x0040
```

Answer (score 0):

### AWK, 39 bytes

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{"poweroff"|getline}
```

Assumes running on Linux and that `AWK` is located at `/bin/awk` and that the `poweroff` command is in the users path.

Since it uses the `BEGIN` block, no input is necessary.  It simply pipes the output of the `poweroff` command into `getline` which it precedes to ignore.

Should work for `Windows` users provided they are in an environment similar to `Cygwin`.

Comment: You don't need to provide the shebang; just add 3 bytes for the flag in your title (something like `### AWK, 39 bytes + 3 (\` -f\`)`

Comment: Do you really have to use `poweroff`? Wouldn't `init 0` or `halt -p` work?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The request was for a program, so to make a standalone program requires the `#!` and the `-f`.  If I just wanted a script I would leave out that line entirely since: `awk 'BEGIN{"poweroff"|getline}'` works just fine. That would save me 13 bytes or so, but I wouldn't consider it a `program`. Just me being pedantic I guess. :)

Comment: @statox You are very probably right.  I can't actually run those commands on my work machine, so I was writing from memory.  As I recall on my machines `init 0` often stops the kernel but does not turn off the machine, and I didn't recall `halt -p`.  So I could save 1 or 2 bytes using those commands.  I know this is code-golf, but I mostly write these to make sure that `AWK` is represented in the solutions. :)

Comment: @RobertBenson I can't test it right now but given [the bash answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107879/40601) I think you can save some bits. Indeed that's nice to have answer with `awk` that's not the first language which comes in mind when we think about codegolf :)

Comment: @statox I know this is beyond the requirements, but `poweroff` often doesn't require root access, whereas the other options do.  I'm not sure why it doesn't. Maybe I'll re-write this to show the various options, but I should be getting back to working right now :p

Comment: @RobertBenson I didn't know about these differences of rights, that's good to know!

Comment: @RobertBenson On this site, you're allowed to specify command line arguments used to run the program. So, for example, you'd run the script using `/path/to/awk -f filename`; that takes 3 bytes more than usual. However, I realise that the `-f` is only so a file can be provided, so you can completely miss out that line entirely like other AWK programs on the site do. It's not being lazy; it's losing every byte you can.

Answer (score 0):

### C, macOS, 18 bytes

```
main(){reboot(8);}
```

This is not a proper shutdown. Usual caveats apply. On my MacBook Air, this resulted in a black screen with a spinning indicator, then a shutdown after a few seconds.

### x64 Assembly, macOS, 11 bytes (untested)

From disassembling the `reboot` function in `libSystem`:

```
movl    $0x2000037, %eax   # b8 37 00 00 02
pushq   $0x08              # 6a 08
popq    %r10               # 41 5a
syscall                    # 0f 05
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5.x (on CentOS Linux), 27 bytes

```hs
system("shutdown -h now");
```

Make system call to shutdown in Linux to halt (`-h`) now.
Changing `-h` to `-r` will shutdown then reboot Linux.

Answer (score 0):

## AutoIt (windows), 11 bytes:

```
Shutdown(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 53 bytes

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s"])
```

Pretty simple code but can do some damage if you haven't saved anything.

### Breakdown

```
import subprocess
```

This imports the `subprocess` module that comes with Python that can be used across the script.

```
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s"])
```

`subprocess.call` runs a process as if you pressed Win + R. It requires a list of strings that will be joined with a space between them and executes it on the PC's shell.

Comment: Instead of `import subprocess` you could do `from subprocess import*` this way you don't spend as many bytes on the next line camping the subprocess module.

Answer (score 0):

## VBA (32-Bit, Windows Only), 72 Bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate function that calls the declared windows function `ExitWindowsEx` from `user32.dll`.

*To be clear, this requires a 32-Bit version of MS Office, not a 32-Bit version of Windows*

#### Declared Function

```vb
Declare Sub ExitWindowsEx Lib"user32"(ByVal A&,ByVal B&)
```

#### Anonymous VBE immediate window function

```vb
ExitWindowsEx 1,0
```

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque - 22 bytes

```
"cmd"{"shutdown /s"}ex
```

Obviously you can not try this online.

On linux you can probably get away with `"shutdown"ex` if your distro offers the shutdown util.

Answer (score 0):

## UEFI Shell - 16 bytes

`reset -s`

In ASCII it would be 8 bytes but since UEFI uses UCS-16, every character takes up 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b) prior to [commit June 4th, 2018](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/commit/6851a84127450743174065d8d7b78229be40f154), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
’À…„‹/p’.E
```

[Try it online without the `.E`.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPMww2PGpY9apj3qGGnfgGQ//8/AA)

**Explanation:**

In the commit of [June 4th, 2018](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/commit/6851a84127450743174065d8d7b78229be40f154), the builtin `.E` has been changed from `run_as_Bash_code` to `run_as_Python_code`. So this only works prior to this commit.

```python
’À…„‹/p’    # Push dictionary string "shutdown/p"
        .E  # Run it as Bash code
```

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands)

```
’£Ø os;os.‚«('À…„‹/p')’.E
```

[Try it online without the `.E`.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPMQ4sPz1DIL7bOL9Z71DDr0GoN9cMNjxqWPWqY96hhp36BuiZQzf//AA)

**Explanation:**

The `.E` builtin is `eval_in_Python` in the current version of 05AB1E.

```python
’£Ø os;os.‚«('À…„‹/p')’    # Push dictionary string "import os;os.system('shutdown/p')"
                       .E  # Evaluate as Python code
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `’À…„‹/p’` is `"shutdown/p"` and `’£Ø os;os.‚«('À…„‹/p')’` is `"import os;os.system('shutdown/p')"`.

*Note: Both work only on Windows. Could be modified to also work on other OS, i.e. `"init 0".E` and `’£Ø os;os.‚«('„‡ƒŸ')’.E` for Linux.*