# Polyglot the English Alphabet!

Tags: polyglot, alphabet, answer-chaining

In this polyglot challenge, you will work together to figure out how to output all the 26 letters of the English alphabet!

**How does this work?**

For each answer, you must pick a new language (or a new major version of a language, for example, python 2 and python 3 are counted separately) that prints the next letter after the previous one.

**Example of an answer.**

Python 3 (Letter a):

```
print("a")
```

**Other rules.**

1. All letters are in lowercase.
2. Language must be Turing complete.
3. The same person cannot post twice in a row.
4. If an answer is found to be invalid it must be deleted.
5. Two users who post "at the same time" will have to let the earlier submission stand.
6. The same language must not be posted more than once.
7. Once we were done we keep going and start back at a.
8. It should print in all previous languages what it did in their original challenge

**More things:**

1. Set the sorting to oldest so this post works well.
2. Try not to make it impossible for the other person or else your post may be set as invalid.

Comment: Remember, [GRUB shell is turning complete](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107884/65836)

Comment: what happens after `z`

Comment: You need to go off the previous answer... And I fixed that other problem @DJMcMayhem

Comment: It feels like you wanted to make this a [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot)

Comment: Yes @MistahFiggins sorry

Comment: I fixed the post I am sorry about the confusion

Comment: I suggest mentioning that it should print in all previous languages what it did in their original challenge. If that is what you meant, this is a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot.

Comment: @Scrooble Thanks... and it is not... that is numbers this is letters

Comment: @arodebaugh It's really just the same task; it doesn't add anything interesting to that challenge

Comment: @arodebaugh It is the same challenge, with _slightly_ different output and a shorter lifespan. Aargh, you beat me to it, HyperNeutrino.

Comment: I hate this website! Why is everyone so picky. I am sorry if I am rude but I am a young programmer (16) and whenever I post anything on any of these sites I always get criticized for something and they never try to answer my question. Maybe I do this site wrong but it should be easy. This site and stack overflow

Comment: You might want to use [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) before you post a challenge next time. It helps you get feedback so that you don't have to edit the question a bunch when it gets to main. Sorry you feel that way :/

Comment: I think rule 8 clears it up the chaining confusion, but I would agree that it is a (near) duplicate of the other linked question.

Comment: @arodebaugh I would recommend you start with asking code-golf questions because they are usually the easiest to think of a unique idea for, specify, etc. answer-chaining is a bit harder to write and by all means avoid popularity-contests for your first while here because few have succeeded in that graveyard of closed questions :P Try using the sandbox, reading the help center, and asking in chat; we're happy to help new users get used to our system! As for SO... just read the help center :P

Comment: Any particular reason for the requirement of Turing completeness? That just excludes languages like [Nhohnhehr](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Nhohnhehr) that could otherwise take part in the challenge.

Comment: @Potato44 I mean some people argue that a programming language has to be turning complete "to be real" so I was just basing it off of that

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes

```
a⎚b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z/xUd@spP//AQ)

:P

Comment: You need to go off the previous answer

Comment: @arodebaugh What? What does that mean?

Comment: I fixed the post I am sorry about the confusion

Comment: Ok, does this fix it?

Comment: Yep it does if it outputs a  in Mathematica and b in charcoal.

Comment: I'm not really sure this works...?

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 1 byte ...............

```
a
```

Comment: The thing I love about CodeGolf is that I am always amazed about how much people manage to golf their code. I mean one byte? That must be magic!