# Is the checkbox not not unchecked?

Tags: code-golf

Doing code review, I stumbled upon the following code, that tests the status of a checkbox:

```
if (!isNotUnchecked()) { ... }
```

I had to brainstorm for 30 minutes to find out what actual checkbox status the code was expecting. Please write me a program that can simplify these silly expressions!

---

The program should accept as input a string representing the expression to simplify (for example: `!isNotUnchecked()`). The program should output a logically equivalent simplified expression, either `isChecked()` or `!isChecked()`.

The method name in the input expression always starts with `is`, contains 0..n `Not`, and ends with `Checked()` or `Unchecked()`.
The method can be prefixed by any number of `!`.

### Examples

```
isChecked() => isChecked()
isUnchecked() => !isChecked()
isNotChecked() => !isChecked()
!isNotChecked() => isChecked()
!!!isNotNotUnchecked() => isChecked()
```

Comment: Is the text always case-sensitive? Would the input be `notunischecked`?

Comment: @SteveFest No, you can assume the input is always in the format that I've described above. You don't need to handle `isnotunchecked` for example.

Comment: leading/trailing whitespace allowed?

Comment: With a function name like that I'd give it 10 to 1 odds that it didn't even actually test the checked condition  consistent with it's naming.

Comment: May I comment on your title? This type of function seems trivial: if it is a triple negative of the term "checked" (or double negative of the term "unchecked") it is not "checked" (or it is "unchecked"). So if the answer to your question is yes, the formulation of your question is valid (it is not not unchecked). However, I find the implication for natural language interesting: if you say "the glass is not empty" it doesn't mean the glass is full (the glass may be half-empty). Now if you say "the glass is not not empty" it means that you know what is a non-empty glass, and this glass is not.

Comment: In other words, you know what is an unchecked box, you know what is a non-unchecked box (it is checked, if and only if "checked" and "unchecked" are the only two possible states, otherwise it could be anything in the checkbox: int, sign...) and for this specific checkbox, it is not (it is not "checked", whether it is with a check mark or anything). If true then, you are sure that the checkbox is not "checked" by anything. If false, well, you know the checkbox is a non-unchecked box but it doesn't necessarily mean it is checked unless there are only two possible states (then it is checked).

Comment: @J Doe thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 32):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(map(s.count,'!NU'))%2*'!'+'isC'+s[-8:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFVcmquRm1igUayXnF@aV6KjrugXqq6pqWqkpa6orq2eWeysrl0crWthFfu/PCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRCFNIzOvoLREQ1PzvxJQVUZqcnZqioamEheQF5qXjML3yy9BVqCIKaIIEQMiZL0A)

Comment: You are a pure genius! Would have never thought of `s[-8:]`

Comment: Surely `'isC'+s[-8:]` is a byte longer than `'isChecked'`?

Comment: but 1 byte shorter than 'isChecked()'

Comment: Can someone explain what `s[-8:]` is/does?

Comment: @EdmundReed It takes the last 8 characters of the input, which are always `hecked()`.

Comment: @xnor gotcha, thanks!

Answer (score 24):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 23 bytes

```
Unc
!C
Not
!
O`is|!
!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfmpfMpejM5ZdfwqXI5Z@QWVyjyKWoyPX/f2axc0ZqcnZqioYmV2YxUBkSD6gaIamIzleEiAARki4A)

#### Explanation

```
Unc
!C
```

Turn `Unchecked` into `!Checked`.

```
Not
!
```

Turn all `Not`s into `!`. We now get something like `!!!is!!!!Checked()`.

```
O`is|!
```

Sort all matches of either `is` or `!`. Since `! < is`, this moves all the `!` to the beginning of the string, so the above example would become `!!!!!!!isChecked()`.

```
!!
```

Remove pairs of `!` to cancel repeated negation.

Answer (score 14):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 26 bytes

```
/Unc/NotC//isNot/!is//!!//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@68fmpes75df4qyvn1kMpPUVM4v19RUV9fX/ZxY7Z6QmZ6emaGhyZRYD1SHxQDrgXEV0viJEBIiQdP0HAA)

Port of my [Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120010/48934).

Answer (score 13):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(map(ord,s))%2*'!'+'isC'+s[-8:]
```

An unnamed function taking the string, `s` and returning a string.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFVcmquRm1igkV@UolOsqalqpKWuqK6tnlnsrK5dHK1rYRX7vyS1uKRYwVZBAySakZqcnZqioamuA@SF5iWj8P3yS5AVKGKKKELEgAhZryZXWn6RAsgehcw8MF1sxcVZUJSZV6IB4ukoqNvaqesopIF5mpr/AQ)**

No need to check for existence of characters when `!`, `Not`, and `Un` all have exactly one odd ordinal (and `c` and `C` are both odd), so just sum up the ordinals and use the value modulo 2 to decide if we want a `!` or not.

Other than that the form is the same as [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120014/53748), as I didn't find anything better. The following is also 43:

```python
lambda s:'!isC'[~sum(map(ord,s))%2:]+s[-8:]
```

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```js
f=
s=>(s.split(/!|n/i).length%2?'':'!')+'isChecked()'
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Works by looking for `!`, `N`, and `n` characters, which invert the checked state. `split` returns an odd array length by default, so we add the `!` when the `split` length is even. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @ETHproductions. Alternative version, also for 50 bytes:

```
s=>`${s.split(/!|n/i).length%2?``:`!`}isChecked()`
```

Comment: Huh, now I go back and look at the other answers, they're all doing this.

Comment: You should be able to drop the global flag from the RegEx to save a byte.

Comment: @Shaggy Actually my length is correct, I just failed to removed the `g` in the latest edit.

Comment: I think you can save a byte with `/!|N/i`

Comment: @ETHproductions I think you meant `/!|N/` without the `i` modifier

Comment: @SplittyDev No, he means to match the `n` of `Unchecked`.

Comment: @Neil Oh, I see. Just woke up and played around with it in node, must have missed some cases cause it seemed to work just fine without the modifier.

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 24 bytes

```
Unc
NotC
+`isNot
!is
!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@al8zll1/izKWdkFkMZHApZhZzKSpy/f@fWeyckZqcnZqiocmVWQxUh8QD6YBzFdH5ihARIELSBQA)

Answer (score 7):

## Java 7, <s>100</s> 77 bytes

```java
String c(String s){return(s.split("[!NU]").length%2<1?"!":"")+"isChecked()";}
```

**Expanation:**

```java
String c(String s){  // Method with String parameter and String return-type
  return(s.split("[!NU]").length
                     //  Count the amount of '!', 'N' and 'U' in the input String (+ 1)
    %2<1?            //  and if they are an even number:
     "!"             //   Start with an examination mark
    :                //  Else:
     "")             //   Start with nothing
    +"isChecked()";  //  And append "isChecked()" to that
}                    // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#lY5BC4JAEIXv/opxINglWKhjBh0650U8iYdtXXRpXcUdgxB/uxl5iSAM5vDgfXxvlJXew2UIADxJMgqmhDrjSlBsCZ4Pnaa@c8wL31pDDLMwTnPkwmpXUrXZH3cnDPGAyLdo/LnS6qYLxjEaJ4C2v9rZu@jvjSmglsYt@iwHyV/zAMnDk65F05No54qsY4p9@DiPfpKpU6vZuKG14vA/Onzz833/Mwbj9AQ)

```java
class M{
  static String c(String s){return(s.split("[!NU]").length%2<1?"!":"")+"isChecked()";}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("isChecked()"));
    System.out.println(c("isUnchecked()"));
    System.out.println(c("isNotChecked()"));
    System.out.println(c("!isNotChecked()"));
    System.out.println(c("!!!isNotNotUnchecked()"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```java
isChecked()
!isChecked()
!isChecked()
isChecked()
isChecked()
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/L3viathan/Aceto), 49 bytes

```
&M"pp"
L!)(de
&c;`Che"
`!d!sick
!',@p"!'
'N'U`!Lu
```

yadda yadda Hilbert curve.

First of all, we push the three important characters on the stack:

```
!'
'N'U
```

Then we set a catch mark and start by reading a single character. We `d`uplicate it and negate it, and if the result of this is truthy (so if the string was empty; so the input ended), we jump to the end:

```
;`
d!
,@
```

With the remaining copy of the input character, we check whether it is contained in the rest of the stack (i.e. if its one of !, N, U). If it's not, we raise an error, throwing us back to our catch mark where we read another character:

```
&c
`!
```

Otherwise, we load what's on quick storage (essentially a register that's initially an empty string; falsy), negate it and send it back to quick storage, then raise the error too (going back to reading characters):

```
&M
L!
```

When the input stopped, we are sent to the end. There, we reverse the direction, push an exclamation mark, and load quick storage and negate it. If that is truthy (i.e. we've had an odd number of negation things), we print the exclamation mark we've pushed:

```
p !'
`!Lu
```

Finally, we push the string in two parts and print them (for space saving reasons):

```
"pp"
)(de
  Che"
  sick
   "
```

Afterwards, the program still runs back to the original beginning, but since none of the commands output anything or have loopy behaviour, that doesn't matter. Actually, the first non-nopping command we reach raises an exception, skipping a majority of the code because we jump to the catch mark, meaning all Aceto sees in that part is:

```
&



!' @
'N'U
```

Since `U` is now not preceeded by a single-quote character and is therefore not seen as a character literal, it gets interpreted as a command: `U` reverses all the elements on the stack (now it's `!`, `N`, `U`, from the top), and `'N` and `'!` push more characters, meaning we end with the stack `[U, N, !, N, !]`.

*Side note: This is the first Aceto program written (in part) with the help of [Aceto's new editor](https://asciinema.org/a/57a0wa44k6lowek7amt4fu649).*

Answer (score 6):

### C, <s>78</s> <s>70</s> 68 Bytes

Thank you Christoph!

```
c;f(char*s){for(c=1;*s;)c^=!!strchr("!NU",*s++);s="!isChecked()"+c;}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#bY8xa8NADIVn36/QHQTuzi60s7gu2bNlalIwio1N6bmcRBbjn93ZUdIMpSlIGh7S0/dWwt7T0JbIYe6n4im9YGQM9J6sZSk0FO/sbu@ayHUdkJOzI2@Hjj66kw@uJlzWMQt8tmP2cJ7GEwQzm@pmCtKxvB0hwQymqtzvy@au7DM9aLtJ/i7a/1X7o2s9@DzrWNDcUZQFTaURwYvyXMEQorZorOv6V9EYvXcbhvQKGz5ktYnSQO@jhIBmWb/z9EStvrkA)

Output:

```
isChecked() => isChecked()
isUnchecked() => !isChecked()
isNotChecked() => !isChecked()
!isNotChecked() => isChecked()
!!!isNotNotUnchecked() => isChecked()
```

Comment: `c;f(char*s){for(c=1;*s;)c^=!!strchr("!NU",*s++);s="!isChecked()"+c;}` using xor to flip `c` saves 2 byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 31 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings).*

30 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
/c/i;$_="!"x(y/UN!//%2).isC.$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@K@frJ9prRJvq6SoVKFRqR/qp6ivr2qkqZdZ7Kynov7/P5DOSE3OTk3R0OTKLA7NS0bi@eWXICQV0fkQASBC1qSIVRgA)

`y/UN!//` counts the number of occurrences of `Un`, `Not`, and `!`. The result is that many `!` modulo 2, followed by `isChecked()`.

---

Another attempt, based on regex, for 38 bytes (Dom Hastings saved 1 byte on that one):

```perl
s/isNot|isUn(c)/!is\u$1/?redo:s/!!//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@F@sn1nsl19Sk1kcmqeRrKmvmFkcU6piqG9flJqSb1Wsr6ior5/@/39msXNGanJ2aoqGJhdIaTISD6gdIamIzocIABGyJkWswgA)

Comment: Your regex version doesn't work because there are two `c`s in `Unchecked`.

Comment: @Neil the regex only replaces the first one (since I'm not using `/g` flag). The test cases look good to me (cf the TryItOnline link). So I don't really see what you mean...

Comment: Sorry, the correct reason that your regex version doesn't work is that although there is a `c` in `Unchecked` there is also one in `Checked`, so when you subsitute it you end up with `CheCked`.

Comment: @Neil Indeed, that's right, I must be blind for not seeing it.. I added `/i` flag to correct this, thanks for pointing it out! :)

Comment: Hey, hope you're doing alright! I haven't been here in a while, but I've had a little play with these for [-2 on the first and -1 on the second](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@K@soBJvq6SoVKFRqR/qp6ivr2qkqaeUWeyckZqcnZqioanEpaxQrJ9ZrOGXX1ITmqepr5hZrG9flJqSb1Wsn6zvrJ9pXayvCNSYzgXkZlpjMQ5omp6KOtQckDGZxaF5Gslgo2JKVQzhxoGN@f8fyXYukNJkJB5QO0JSEZ0PEQAiZE2KWIUB)

Comment: @DomHastings Hey! Awesome, thanks a lot! Happy to see you back around :-)

Answer (score 6):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>39</s> 30 bytes

```scala
s=>"!"*(s.sum%2)+"isChecked()"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/scala#dUxNC4IwGL73K94Ngq1gh46FQnStLtIPWPNVZ7oNNyMQf7uNgkgieA7Pt73WqAKcpDaAj4Am97B3Dga4ywaKLWSh06aEJP0wGCafpJTQFfPC9@1yw9dU@0OF6oY543Qad68147Gsrchs3ykUPuTaiBLDURv0opWOFVwUtkOpKubieWgMh3GanS2iuhg102cbvgvk1yFvL2K@JX@SJw)

Unfortunately I couldn't get it to deduce the type of s.

Edit: Moved the type declaration to the header (I think this is allowed, if not I'll put it back).

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```ruby
->x{?!*(x.count('!UN')%2)+'isChecked()'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7T9r2tXUW2vqKVRoZecX5pXoqGuGOqnrqlqpKmtnlnsnJGanJ2aoqGpXvu/KDUxJSczL7VYLzexoLqmoqagtKRYITG6Irb2vxKSUiUuIC80LxmF75dfgqxAEVNEESIGRMh6AQ)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice answer. :)

Comment: @MartinEnder thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
…Unc„!C:'€–™'!:'!†„!!K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymr/P@oYVloXvKjhnmKzlbqj5rWPGqY/Khlkbqilbrio4YFIHFF7/@VSof3K9jaKRzer6TzP7PYOSM1OTs1RUOTK7MYqBmJ55dfgpBUROcrQkSACFmXInZxAA)

Answer (score 3):

### PHP (5.5 - 5.6), <s>52</s> <s>50</s> 49 Bytes

```php
<?='!'[count(spliti('!|N',$argn))%2]?>isChecked()
```

Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12de9387b5efbc4d90f85439f33dfd291dd19ada).

```
-2 Bytes by @Titus. Ty :)
-1 Byte  by @ETHproductions. Ty :)
```

### PHP (>=5.5), <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 61

```php
for($b=b;$a=$argn[$i++];)$b^=$a;echo$b&"!"|" ","isChecked()";
```

Without regex it gets a bit more compex :) Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c1f850c8bf8ded4d60361c8f95ffd90d7df4b28).

```
-4 Bytes by @Titus. Ty :)
```

Comment: `error_reporting` default value is `E_ALL&~E_NOTICE&~E_STRICT&~E_DEPRECATED`.

Comment: @Titus beating JS in a regex challenge yay!

Comment: `$b^=$a` Very nice find! You can also do that without the PHP tags at the same size.

Comment: 61 bytes if leading whitespace is allowed: `for($b=b;$a=$argn[$i++];)$b^=$a;echo$b&"!"|" ","isChecked()";`

Comment: @Titus I have to admit that it was inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120046/29637).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>16</s>  15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
OSḂ⁾!iṫ⁾sCø³ṫ-7
```

A full program that takes the string as a command line argument and prints the result

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/@OGOpkeN@xQzH@5cDaSLnQ/vOLQZyNY1////v6KiYmaxX34JEIXmJWekJmenpmhoAgA)**

`OSḂ⁾!iṫ-7³ṫṭ⁾sC` or `OSḂ⁾!iṫ-7³ṫ⁾sC;` would both also work for 15.

#### How?

Uses the same idea as [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120046/53748), but saves bytes using a different construction of `!isC` or `isC` and some implicit printing in Jelly...

```
OSḂ⁾!iṫ⁾sCø³ṫ-7 - Main link: s
O               - cast to ordinals
 S              - sum
  Ḃ             - mod 2
   ⁾!i          - literal ['!','i']
      ṫ         - tail -> ['i'] if OSḂ was 0; ['!','i'] if OSḂ was 1
                - this is printed due to the following starting a new leading
                - constant chain. Printing smashes so either "i" or "!i" is printed.
       ⁾sC      - literal ['s','C']
                - this is printed (as "sC") due to the following niladic chain.
          ø     - start a new niladic chain
           ³    - program's first input (3rd command line argument), s
            ṫ-7 - tail from index -7 = ['h','e','c','k','e','d','(',')']
                - implicit print (of "hecked()")
```

previous @ 16 bytes 9 (using concatenation and pairing with the same underlying idea):

```
OSḂ⁾!iṫ;⁾sC,ṫ€-7
```

Comment: Ah, darn, I thought I was on to something with the mod 2 trick. Then I found this :P I had this for 18 bytes, maybe it could help: `OS1&”!x;“isC”;ṫ-7$`

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
ÇOÉ'!×…isCyR8£RJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymr/H@43f9wp7ri4emPGpZlFjtXBlkcWhzk9b9S6fB@BVs7hcP7lXT@A8UzUpOzU1M0NLkyi0PzkpF4fvklCElFdL4iRASIkHUpYhcHAA)

Uses the trick of summing the ordinals from [Jonathan Allan's python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120046/47066).

**Explanation**

```
 ÇO                # sum of ascii values of input
   É               # is odd
    '!×            # repeat "!" that many times
       …isC        # push the string "isC"
           IR8£R   # push the last 8 chars of input
                J  # join everything to string
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
o"!N" l u)ç'! +`‰C”×B()
```

## Explanation

```
 o"!N" l u)ç'! +`‰C”×B()
Uo"!N" l u)ç'! +`‰C”×B()`
Uo"!N"                     # Only keep "!", "n" and "N" from the input
           ç'!             # Repeat the string "!" by
       l u)                # the parity of the length of the newly formed string
               +`‰C”×B()` # and concatenate with the string "isChecked()"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5@vpOinpJCjUKp5eLm6ooJ2wqFO50NTDk930tD8/19JMbPYL7/EOSM1OTs1RUNTCQA)

Comment: Wait... How does... Why... Is `o` case-insensitive? I did not know that...

Comment: I didn't know it either, but I found out when I tested with "!NU". The lowercase "n" in "Unchecked" also remained, so I could drop the "U" : )

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, <s>82</s> <s>61</s> 60 Bytes

Small tweak, added one more infix operator:

```
"!"~Table~Mod[#~StringCount~{"o","n","!"},2]<>"isChecked()"&
```

Previously:

```
"!"~Table~Mod[StringCount[#,{"o","n","!"}],2]<>"isChecked()"&
```

Count up all the o's, n's and !'s then mod 2 and put that many ! in front.

Old version:

```
"!"~Table~Mod[StringCount[StringReplace[#,{{"o","n"}->"!"}],"!"],2]<>"isChecked()"&
```

Answer (score 2):

## sed, <s>37</s> 38 bytes

```
:;s/is(Not|Un)/!is/;s/!!//;t;s/ch/Ch/
```

37 + 1 for `-r` switch:

```
sed -r ':;s/is(Not|Un)/!is/;s/!!//;t;s/ch/Ch/'
```

Comment: That last `s/c/C/` caused problems for the Perl 5 answer...

Comment: Yeah, looks like the `s/c/C/` is catching the second "c" in cases without "Un"

Comment: Also, you can save a byte by dropping the `g` and moving the `s/!!//` inside the loop.

Comment: [You don't need the switch to get 37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K05N@f/fiqtYP7M4NC9ZXzGz2FkfzPPLLwHxQBxFRX19rpL//0GSGanJ2akpGppcqGygXiQeUC9CUhGdDxEAImRNiliFAQ "sed 4.2.2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>35</s>  31 bytes

```perl6
{'!'x m:g/<[!NU]>/%2~'isChecked()'}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#dc7LTsMwEAXQvb/iegG205BIILEgTYTUfTfQFWFRnKG1aB7CDiqqmh9jx48FNzyUgpAsS55zPTOtJbxcRjph5StOdV0Q0n4nuNiivFrF0zs@X9xn8cl5J4ydrUk/USGV2Pc@fu3IOqTYmIqsVO9vka7LBxkjv0EQ4CKKAsQqYa2fceujCWs2ywqT4V/CHuvnrxZnGWRuqqZ1YU7bhrSjQmHHAGNx2EkOqEJ8a4ihgg4Caeav7ofYvh9tetDRkxm7qPQY@bHOazf7l/lfP2L@GfDn15BR6gM)

```perl6
{'!'x tr/!NU//%2~'isChecked()'}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#dY7BasJAEIbv@xT/gu3upmkWWuglRATvXqy3XOpmSpdqEtxNsYh5MW99sXTVKrEiLAM73zfzT@MIXy@JSdnyG/emKghZtxFcrOFXmk9mWt89tcK68QeZTyqkEtsuqCNPziPDwpbkpPrZJaZazqVGPkUU4TlJImiVsibsfw1qyurFW4mHw1zK3qvV34rHIWRuy7rxcU7rmoynQmHDAOuwv0eGtEFIOjgqxkmKjx20EMiGobRnxLZd7@A97X2ZdbPS9CG/pJPKj29ifs0vMD8K4f0L6Vm/)
(requires mutable input string which will be mutilated)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{
  #(
    '!'
  x               # string repeat

    # m:g/<[!NU]>/
    tr/!NU//      # find the number of negatives
      % 2         # modulus 2
  #)

  ~                # string concat

    'isChecked()'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Sed, 36 Bytes

Same idea as all the other direct substitution answers.

```
:
s/Unc/NotC/
s/isNot/!is/
s/!!//
t
```

Answer (score 2):

## Windows Batch, 120 bytes

Previously <sub>268 257 253 245 239 221 182 176 169 123</sub> bytes

```
@set a=%1
@set s=#%a:~,-2%
@set s=%s:!=N#%
@for %%a in (%s:N= %)do @set/ac+=5
@if %c:~-1%==0 cd|set/p=!
@echo isC%a:~-8%
```

The programs replaces all the `!` into `N#`. Because now all negation signs, !(Now it is `N#`), `Not`, and `Un` contains `N`, the program can counts the number of appearance of `N` and determines if an leading `!` is required.

Each time the program counts an `N`, the counter is added by 5. The reason for adding 5 is because each alternating values when adding 5 ends in either 0 or 5. This can be used to determine whether the value is odd or even and the leading `!` us added if required.

In addition, xnor's last-eight-character trick is utilized.

Comment: One would think programming in windows batch would be impossible...

Comment: Of course...... Batch scripting is absurd....

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 90 bytes

```
=IF(ISODD(SEARCH("C",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Un","!"),"Not","!"))),"","!")&"isChecked()"
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 55 Bytes

```php
<?=preg_match_all("#!|N#i",$argn)&1?"!":""?>isChecked()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVVJUzCz2yy8BotA854zU5OzUFA1NJWsue7v/Nva2BUWp6fG5iSXJGfGJOTkaSsqKNX7KmUo6YM2aaob2SopKVkpK9naZxXDN//8DAA)

## PHP, 58 Bytes

```php
<?=preg_match_all("#[!NU]#",$argn)%2?"!":"","isChecked()";
```

instead `"#[!NU]#"` you can use `"#[!N]#i"`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVVJUzCz2yy8BotA854zU5OzUFA1NJWsue7v/Nva2BUWp6fG5iSXJGfGJOTkaSsrRin6hscpKOmDdmqpG9kqKSlZKSjpKmcVIuv//BwA)

## PHP, 68 Bytes

Version without Regex

```
for(;$c=$argn[$i++];)$d^=!trim($c,"UN!");echo"!"[!$d],"isChecked()";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVVJUzCz2yy8BotA854zU5OzUFA1NJev/aflFGtYqybZgZdEqmdrasdaaKilxtoolRZm5GirJOkqhfopKmtapyRn5SopK0YoqKbE6SpnFyIb8BwA)

Comment: `<?=preg_match_all("#[!UN]#",$argn)&1?"!":""?>isChecked()` -2 bytes

Comment: Had exactly the same answer before I came up with `count(split())` :D @Titus nice idea !

Comment: @Titus nice idea to leave PHP

Comment: [66 Bytes without Regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120037/29637). Can you beat it ? :)

Comment: `" !"[$d&1]` saves another byte if leading whitespace is ok. `$d^=!trim($c,"UN!")` saves 3 bytes (because you need no `&1` anymore).

Comment: @Titus Yes one example more that you have more knowledge then myself. Thank You and for the trailing whitespace problem I have make `"!"[!$d]` instead

Comment: @JörgHülsermann I'm pretty sure that if you use a closing tag `?>`  you need the opening tag `<?`. Anyway updated to a 65 byte version :)

Comment: @Christoph you are right I have forget it sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>29</s> <s>28</s> <s>25</s> 21 bytes

```
f“NU!”LḂ”!x;“µịÆẹṠƊẹ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@5/2qGGOX6jio4a5Pg93NAEpxQproNChrQ93dx9ue7hr58OdC451AelDu/8f3XO4/VHTmiwgBipRsLVTAKqP/P8/Wj2z2DkjNTk7NUVDU10HyAvNS0bh@@WXICtQxBRRhIgBEbLeWAA)

```
f“NU!”LḂ”!x;“µịÆẹṠƊẹ»  Main link, argument is z
f“NU!”                 Filter to only keep "NU!"
      LḂ”!x            Repeat exclamation mark by the parity of the length
           ;“µịÆẹṠƊẹ»  Concatenate to "isChecked()"
```

-4 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan!
-4 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan!  (by using compressed strings)

Comment: Save the interface Lynn made [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70932/53748) as a module (say jellyCompress.py), then that would have been formed with `jellyCompress.Compress().string("is").dictionary("Checked").string("()").go()`. (If you're running in a Windows  cmd install and switch to the font DejaVu Sans Mono and change the codepage with the command `chcp 65001` before launching Python to get the characters to display)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 19 bytes

```
`‰C”×B()`i'!pU¬xc u
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=YIlDlNdCKClgaSchcFWseGMgdQ==&input=LW1SIFsKImlzQ2hlY2tlZCgpIiwKImlzVW5jaGVja2VkKCkiLAoiaXNOb3RDaGVja2VkKCkiLAoiIWlzTm90Q2hlY2tlZCgpIiwKIiEhIWlzTm90Tm90VW5jaGVja2VkKCkiCl0=)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
`‰C”×B()`i'!pUq xc u

`‰C”×B()`   Compressed string for "isChecked()"
i     Insert the following string at the beginning...
'!p     "!" repeated the following number of times...
Uq        Split the input into chars
xc        Sum the charcodes
u         Modulo 2
```

Using the charcode-sum trick from [Jonathan Allan's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120046/78410).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 119 bytes

```pascal
var s:string;j:word;c:char;begin read(s);for c in s do j:=j+ord(c);if 1=j mod 2then write('!');write('isChecked()')end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYoxDgIhEEWvMlRAjCZaQrayt/MAOMwuoMJmhrjHxy00@cXLe38NguF1nFcc4xMYxEnnXBdf3NY4enSYAvsHLbkCU4hGrJ8bA8IuBGKD4qZy2L8Grc8znKcC7xbh0hNV2Dh3Mlpp63@Y5ZoInxSN1ZZqPI2hlMpya33fveK/fgE)

Using method that almost every answer does, summing codepoints of characters in the input, then checking parity of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 32 bytes

```
/!!//Not/!/Unc/!C/is!/!is/#input
```

### Explained

Works like the Retina answer

```
/!!//                            #Remove all !! pairs
     Not/!/                      #Replace all Nots with !s
           Unc/!C/               #Replace any Unc's with !C (Turning Unchecked into !Checked)
                  is!/!is/       #Float all !'s past the is to the left
                          #input #Take the stdin as input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/X19RUV/fL79EX1E/NC9ZX9FZP7NYUV8xs1hfOTOvoLTk/39FIAeoAIiACjJSk7NTUzQ0/wMA)