# Display numbers lacking 2's

Tags: code-golf, sequence, kolmogorov-complexity

Display numbers from one to one-hundred (in increasing order), but number 2 shouldn’t appear anywhere in the sequence. So, for example, the numbers two (`2`) or twenty-three (`23`) shouldn't be in the sequence.

Here is an example output, with newlines separating the numbers:

```
1
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
30
31
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

Comment: I assume the winning criteria is code-golf right?

Comment: Does the order matter? ('Sequence' seems to imply that it does.)

Comment: Can we output from 100 to 1 instead of 1 to 100?

Comment: Yes the order matters.

Comment: Our site does not work the same way as other sites from the Stack Exchange network. Regarding accepted answers, please take [this comment from Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173159/letters-challenge#comment417762_173160) into account. And please add a winning criterion.

Comment: Might I suggest using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/76162) in the future to get feedback on your challenges before posting?

Comment: the shortest possible python code wins.

Comment: @Monolica If the shortest answer wins, you'll need the tag `[code-golf]`. [Here is a list for all available winning criteria tags for future reference.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/52210)

Comment: I added [tag:code-golf] since that seems to be the closest applicable tag for OP's intended challenge

Comment: From review queue, I think as it is the question is under-specified. If the order matters, edit that into the question. People should not need to read comments to know the challenge.

Comment: Instead of replying in the comments, **[edit] the post**.

Comment: Also, **[arbitrarily restricting the language is disallowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/69850)**.

Comment: @user202729 Arbitrary restriction is unwelcome, not disallowed.

Comment: Can we print leading zeroes for any number?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Uh, that's right, it's "avoided".

Comment: May we output 0 as well? Or 0 to 99?

Comment: Pretty cool that this has a score of 22 votes

Comment: I think that [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173189/display-numbers-lacking-2s/253059#253059) wins with 5 bytes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
тLʒ2å_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YpPPqUlGh5fG//8PAA)

**Explanation**

```
тL       # push [1 ... 100]
  ʒ      # filter, keep only elements that
   2å_   # does not contain 2
```

Answer (score 26):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), <s>2399</s> <s>2391</s> <s>2370</s> <s>1783</s> <s>1773</s> 1706 bytes

*-8 bytes for realizing that, instead of leaving a certain passenger at Sunny Side Park forever, it's more worth it to throw them off of Riverview Bridge. Ah, what a lovely town this is.*

*-21 bytes for taking out a comment I stupidly left in.*

*-587 bytes by simply changing the entire way I went about this (apparently a shorter way is by arithmetic; integer-dividing [17, 27, 37, 47,...] by 9 yields the sequence, but you gotta skip over the 20's yourself.)*

*-17 bytes for the realization that any quotes-encased string without a space doesn't need quotes after all (thanks Jo King!).*

*-67 bytes for the realization that linebreaks are optional.*

```
17 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 1 l 2 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:e 1 l 2 r.[B]Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.9 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:s 2 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Go to Divide and Conquer:e 1 l 2 r 3 r 2 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Go to Trunkers:e 1 r 3 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:e 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.\n is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:n 5 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Go to Cyclone:s 1 r 1 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.177 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:s 2 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:w 1 l.Switch to plan C if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.100 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Switch to plan D.[C]10 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.[D]Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Sunny Skies Park:w 1 r.Go to Addition Alley:n 1 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.917 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:s 2 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:w 1 l.Switch to plan E if no one is waiting.Switch to plan F.[E]Go to Go More:n 1 l.Go to Cyclone:w 1 r.Switch to plan B.[F]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVRdT4MwFP0r9823ZmjMsr1tbPNJXcISH5CHCgUaasva4uTXI4OiW10AY2J84Ou299x7zj1U43daVc4UqIIDppryBLAGT2MZppRF8FC8EimYSEp0J0CLi0vzAzjA4Bpk82zfGdrSMCtywJBjpQhPiIREHCvUMG4ZMsGJATVfc9LhIH8ZjEnv27OibzQigHkEruD7gkg0@yVPdeTV9PfDwi3m94UvxnBTX62C/eg7WfCMSGUwu88GqUVxBrTfpQSW@IWwmKqUyI6xHTaIQ/1shdLwGMc0JOiZWwI/SaqJvFKwIrnQptB5cM7hdoRhTsu0MCeRGsP5lI9ZplKGxvDgFlFUdy44LBgjZe/W9b7ArKbgCsnr@TrT6Z9Yyyrb4p0H258ReQeqw/S4nDPMwQUaAxdQC3LSaG8tr@C8BC@jRMEWyww5k8kYklblFfLdwBmV6a@CHoX4oBWt@Rksi0ajTyfdeYax0RjXXz6/eHf@od8eXtagZ84/99f6sr@sXRvkr82I6/u9kEYyS8Z2QlbuEvmboKo@AA)

This one isn't winning me any code golf competitions anytime soon, but I decided to try out the esolang Taxi.

Taxi is an esolang in which all programming is done by picking up and dropping off passengers at various stops in the fictional town of Townsburg. Of course, your taxicab will sometimes run out of gas, so you also need to visit gas stations every so often, and pay using the credits you receive as fare (in this case, I only need to stop for gas - at Go More - once per loop iteration!).

I used some tricks that reduce the filesize a bit, such as rephrasing directions like `east 1st left, 2nd right` as `e 1 l 2 r`, removing the word `the` where it is optional, and using the least complicated route towards all of my destinations (not necessarily the shortest path).

I hate this shorter solution more than the one I originally came up with. This solution down here is a more general way of accomplishing the task, which could start and end anywhere you want. Here it is, in its entirety.

## 2245 bytes (way more general)

```
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 1 l 2 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:e 1 l 2 r.[B]Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:n 2 r 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 5 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.0 is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:w.Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 3 r 1 l 1 r.Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.[C]Switch to plan E if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.2 is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:n 1 l 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.Go to Crime Lab:n 3 r 2 r.Switch to plan D if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 5 l.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to KonKat's:e 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 2 l.Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan C.[D]Go to Chop Suey:n 5 r 1 l.Switch to plan C.[E]Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.0 is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:w 1 l 1 r 2 l.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.Go to Crime Lab:n 3 r 2 r.Switch to plan F if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Riverview Bridge.Go to Cyclone:n 4 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Riverview Bridge:n 2 r.\n is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:w 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Go to Starchild Numerology:s 1 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.Switch to plan G.[F]Go to Cyclone:s 1 r 1 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Riverview Bridge.Go to Riverview Bridge:n 2 r.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 2 l 3 l 2 r.[G]Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Addition Alley:e 1 l 2 r 3 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.101 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 l 1 l 3 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.Go to Magic Eight:w 1 r 2 r 1 r.Switch to plan H if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 2 r.Switch to plan B.[H]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVVNb6MwEP0rc@vNapLthVvz0VTqbjfaVKq0LAeXODCqYyPjlObXp2BwQtxCINsL4DEzb94be0bTd9zvB4ApZBQ1igiohqWmKoyRr@Bxu2FKchntyFyCll9ueRkMgMMQlHmX35wsMHzdJkAhoWnKRMQURLJAyMNMdiGXglVBq5XHbBzij4M299vVKk9WCrjlnO1akZ5iBmP6wvga05gpy8M1e8LkX2D3z1vATRfOsUxguWU2hb9SbszDE@TaqcCzQs3UVQpTlkhdOZwavawV7ZEqJTNYUB3nD/VaxXDNee6jQ92U5WUzNRU57vqTYJmhDuPip4RTATPANQgJuQo1Bu0yKNww@ElfyPAC0sIkMzon9QGjImTXFd2izA6TaX8mD1I8UH2VNkt7cyZPJ4JdlrJ/U3mLY9leVkeJCfGngetRcDEeX/w9CxrBKwjj2K1gF92EA05BtlM3@@bTc9f/9PzBN6bekGUwVriKPveUHx16ykKmGn6v1xhafzds2djIP3GRrv3xaxZTf2XnQtsASWvnsSTt6Dsn/l1wKtDR51zTblC6QanWOTcsm085o@Z9ZlQZ9tR4HHhVE27n8YtGGMIMo1iTwfX/Dm1x0HvUQcM6dhm0ZjEX0Bb60924v2BGNIxZW20HYUz8@2C//wA)

And if mega-cheating is allowed, this one is way shorter than either of the last two.

## 456 bytes (totally cheating)

```
1\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n30\n31\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n41\n43\n44\n45\n46\n47\n48\n49\n50\n51\n53\n54\n55\n56\n57\n58\n59\n60\n61\n63\n64\n65\n66\n67\n68\n69\n70\n71\n73\n74\n75\n76\n77\n78\n79\n80\n81\n83\n84\n85\n86\n87\n88\n89\n90\n91\n93\n94\n95\n96\n97\n98\n99\n100 is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:w 1 l 2 r 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XdA/a8MwEIfhr3JbNxNV/zMXOjZbFy0mOEY0nIOtkn5791VJoXQQgrtHP@nUxq@676aoLeqK@qKhaCyaiuai5sCiaega2oa@ARiEgRiMxdgegLEYi7EYi7EYi3EYh3H9FozDOIzDOIzDeIzHeIzvT8F4jMd4jMcETMAETMCE/l5MwARMwERMxERMxERM7ENhIiZiEiZhEiZhEiZhUp8ckzAZkzEZkzEZkzEZk/v3/PzPQeom97G2qrOMTd7X2qb1aZOX6ba04XWRtvwrHu9i5CrPsj7263Cq54/Pm4xyG7dt0nlaZV56IodPy9bk7XKp5@kR96dyVDLW36xh378B)

Comment: That quotes thing is a helpful one, thanks. However, I disagree with the "don't have to go to the Taxi Garage" thing. Is exiting with an error allowed? I can't find a good set of general rules on this.

Comment: Yeah, generally STDERR is ignored. [Relevant meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/76162)

Comment: Some of my answers could benefit from that.

Answer (score 24):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
k=7
exec"k+=10;print(k>177)*10+k/9;"*81
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9vWnCu1IjVZKVvb1tDAuqAoM69EI9vO0NxcU8vQQDtb39JaScvC8P9/AA)

Uses arithmetic operations only to generate numbers without 2's.

The value `k` follows the arithmetic progression `17, 27, 37, 47, ...`, which when floor-divided by 9 gives `1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,...` which counts up numbers not ending in 2. To skip 20 through 29, outputs are increased by 10 past a certain threshold.

Comment: +1 clever use of the arithmetic progression!!

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

Returns the sequence as a comma-separated string.

```javascript
f=(n=98)=>n?f(n-=n-27?n%10?1:2:11)+[,n+3]:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADA1wSKGa0dKsF8SHQQ0yhkNzL6/jZzhS/U@Jz3q5H2xJydQDdP0i3os0DtUJvRYwO9B2ssgFRri2rYLHAkrFRSV@gQWUjJPw)

#### Why doing it this way?

We could iterate from \$1\$ to \$100\$ and test each number with `/2/.test(n)`, which is a rather concise statement. But in this scenario, we'd have to handle empty entries with something like `(/2/.test(n)?'':...)`, which adds a couple more bytes.

For example, this would work for [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADA57iLpthNQX1IdBDTKGSNlL5vM3f8Yk/v9YyF2pHnLA7IaXSevDGBLKhVyZH7AMLAmN1IiB15AeIaZ2rUW82ythMKIM4f):

```javascript
f=(n=1)=>n>99?n:(/2/.test(n)?'':[n,,])+f(n+1)
```

Or this would work for [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEADA4@wu5atPwTxI9CGmUcgaKV3fZu7whRbf6@mC65HGyA7ZGa3JrewzsjA0oVqU7Kl1ZPIAdpt5JwswYuVWS5KlnpiRaPw), if a leading comma is acceptable:

```javascript
f=(n=100)=>n?f(n-1)+(/2/.test(n)?'':[,n]):''
```

All in all (and until proven otherwise), it turns out to be shorter to *skip right away* all values of \$n\$ that contain a \$2\$.

#### Commented

```javascript
f =                 // f is a recursive function taking:
(n = 98) =>         // n = counter, initialized to 98
  n ?               // if n is not equal to 0:
    f(              //   prepend the result of a recursive call:
      n -=          //     update n:
        n - 27 ?    //       if n is not equal to 27:
          n % 10 ?  //         if n is not a multiple of 10:
            1       //           subtract 1 from n
          :         //         else:
            2       //           subtract 2 from n
        :           //       else (n = 27):
          11        //         subtract 11 from n (--> 16)
    ) +             //   end of recursive call
    [, n + 3]       //   append a comma, followed by n + 3; notice that this is the value
                    //   of n *after* it was updated for the recursive call; at the first
                    //   iteration, we have: n = 98 -> updated to 97 -> n + 3 = 100
  :                 // else (n = 0):
    1               //   output the first term '1' and stop recursion
```

Comment: This is so cool!

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQ4zhDfqCdgnaQaCGmUcgYKS27@vTeFd/Y03PeQ1HbM3Px5AMFaxdyYGajR@4DCBch3EpSbjgVUB8hp0a91axrO6AAIv8) using [your trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105982/61613) if we could have a leading comma.

Answer (score 12):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 19 bytes

```r
grep(2,1:100,inv=T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P70otUDDSMfQytDAQCczr8w2RPP/fwA)

Comment: `grep(2,1:100,inv=T)` for 19.

Comment: Ha - this was what I tried at first but with `v=F` as well because obviously, I thought to myself, I want the *values* and not the *indices*...duh!

Comment: Inverting the regex itself is a byte shorter (in this case).

Comment: Doesn't work, still lets 2s past. You'd need `^[^2]*$` which is, um, not shorter.

Comment: What, are we supposed to check our answers now?

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
print[n for n in range(1,101)if'2'not in`n`]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM68kOk8hLb9IIU8hM0@hKDEvPVXDUMfQwFAzM03dSD0vvwQonpCXEPv/PwA)

Answer (score 10):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 22 bytes

```perl6
put grep {!/2/},1..100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@gtEQhvSi1QKFaUd9Iv1bHUE/P0MDg/38A)

There's probably a better way to do the code block, but I couldn't find a regex adverb to invert the match

Comment: remove the brackets around the numbers. Otherwise it is fine.

Comment: @Monolica Fixed

Comment: @Monolica It seems a little weird that you singled my answer out as not allowed to print as a list, where so many other answers do so. On the other hand, it doesn't cost me any bytes, so whatever

Answer (score 7):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>22</s> 16 bytes

```powershell
1..100-notmatch2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz9DAQDcvvyQ3sSQ5w@j/fwA)

*-6 bytes thanks to mazzy*

Generates the range `1` to `100`, then pulls out those objects where they do `-notmatch` the number `2`. Running the `-notmatch` against an array like this acts like a filter on the array. Each item is left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

Comment: ? `1..100-notmatch2`

Comment: @mazzy Of course, why didn't I think of that? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
Lõs kø2
```

---

```
Lõs kø2     Full Program
Lõs         Range ["1"..."100"] (numbers are casted to string)
    k       Remove
     ø2     anything that contains "2"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@fw1mKF7MM7jP7/BwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>48</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

Thanks @JonathanFrech for fifteen bytes saved, and @xnor for another two! I missed a big golf and didn't realize `main=print$` can be omitted.

```
filter(all(/='2').show)[1..100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeiUMGloFCekVqUqlBdoWD7Py0zpyS1SCMxJ0dD31bdSF1Trzgjv1wz2lBPz9DAIPa/gkLtfwA)

Easily extended by changing the `100`. Stringifies all the numbers and keeps only those without a `'2'`.

Comment: [See this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12945/73111); the `main=print$` is not necessary. Have you tested your code? I do not think that `elem'2'` is valid syntax. Why `map`? Simply `filter(not.elem '2'.show)[1..100]` does the job.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Wow, missed that. :/ No clue where that space went! It's there in the TIO...

Comment: Haskell has `notElem` for `not.elem`, but even shorter is `all(/='2')`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 16

- 1 byte saved thanks to @Dennis.

```bash
seq 100|sed /2/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UMHQwKCmODVFQd9IP@X/fwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
100*
.
$.>`¶
A`2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vQwECLS49LRc8u4dA2LscEo///AQ) Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ovs, although the last line now includes a newline. Explanation:

```
100*
```

Insert 100 characters.

```
.
$.>`¶
```

Replace each character with the number of characters up to and including that character, plus a newline.

```
A`2
```

Remove all entries that contain a `2`.

Comment: Does `.` `$.>\`¶` work for the second stage?

Comment: @ovs I had had something more complicated before and switched to `L$` to avoid a leading newline, so I hadn't realised I could switch back, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 10, 67 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=0;++i<101;)if(i%10!=2&i/10!=2)System.out.println(i);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BDoIwEETvfMV60LQhIHgt@AdyIfFiPNQCZrEUQksTQ/j2WpDLTnazM/NabnnUVh8nJNcabhzVHACgMvXYcFFDsa4AtscKBLmvYinztyXwQxtuUEABCnJwNrrOTT8S7wbMExaGmKVJyig2BI9pcsgvJzxvSsuvNnUX95OJh9EbpCJI2eLYGjtML@lj9/Stu/NkpDT@9f14Aqd/LBULoiYpd6LF/QA)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                           // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=0;++i<101;)        //  Loop `i` in the range (0, 101)
    if(i%10!=2                 //   If `i` modulo-10 is not 2
       &i/10!=2)               //   And `i` integer-divided by 10 is not 2 either
      System.out.println(i);}  //    Print `i` with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 5):

## Powershell, 19 bytes

```
1..100-split'.*2.*'
```

This script show null-value instead 'numbers with 2 inside' and completely solves the task 'number 2 shouldn’t appear anywhere in the sequence'.

Output:

```
1


3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11


13
14
15
16
17
18
19




















30
31


33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41


43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51


53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61


63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71


73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81


83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91


93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

### Powerhsell (output does not contain null-values), 24 bytes

```
1..100-split'.*2.*'-ne''
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 44 bytes

```
time {if ![regexp 2 [incr i]] {puts $i}} 100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6M01BMbooNT21okDBSCE6My@5SCEzNlahuqC0pFhBJbO2VsHQwOD/fwA)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 47 bytes

```
time {if [incr i]%10!=2&$i/10!=2 {puts $i}} 100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6M00hOjMvuUghM1bV0EDR1khNJVMfzFCoLigtKVZQyaytVTA0MPj/HwA)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 50 bytes

```
time {if {2 ni [split [incr i] ""]} {puts $i}} 100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6M02h2kghL1MhurggJ7NEITozL7lIITNWQUkptlahuqC0pFhBJbO2VsHQwOD/fwA)

Comment: **# [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 49 bytes** [`time {if [string f 2 [incr i]]==-1 {puts $i}} 100`](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6M00hurikKDMvXSFNwUghOjMvuUghMzbW1lbXUKG6oLSkWEEls7ZWwdDA4P9/AA) — **Failed outgolf!**

Comment: You could replace your test with a `regexp`:
`![regexp 2 [incr i]]` for -3 bytes

Comment: @david How was it possible I didn't come with the solution suggested by you of using regular expressions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç░τ╒╜h
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80b0e7d5bd68&i=&a=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
AJ  10 squared
f   output each value in [1 .. n] satisfying the following filter
 E  get array of decimal digits in number
 2#     count the number of 2s
 !  logical not
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=AJ%0910+squared%0Af%09output+each+value+in+[1+..+n]+satisfying+the+following+filter%0A+E%09get+array+of+decimal+digits+in+number%0A+2%23+%09count+the+number+of+2s%0A+%21+%09logical+not&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
Print@⌈Range[1,100,10/9]~Drop~{18,26}⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxOFRT0dQYl56arShjqGBARDrW8bWuRTlF9RVG1roGJnVPurp/P8fAA)

The arithmetic sequence 1, 19/9, 29/9, 39/9, ... grows at just the right rate that taking the ceiling skips all the numbers ending in 2. Then we get rid of 20 through 29 by `Drop`ping the values at indices 18 through 26.

Comment: I don't know if the consensus is that the `Print` is necessary, but who really cares, anyway.

Comment: _[...] but who really cares, anyway._ -- that's the spirit ...

Comment: Do `\[LeftCeiling]` and `\[RightCeiling]` really count as a single byte :)

Comment: @user6014 I'm counting them as the 3 bytes they take up in Unicode, but it's still a bit cheaper than an actual `Ceiling` command.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sounds fair ! Neat solution.

Answer (score 4):

### [C (GCC)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/), <strike>62</strike> 55 Bytes

*• 7 Bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech*

`f(n){for(n=0;++n-101;n/10-2&&n%10-2&&printf("%d,",n));}`

Loops from 1 to 100 and prints the number only if 2 is not in the ones or tens place.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOi2/SCPP1sBaWztP19DA0DpP39BA10hNLU8VQhcUZeaVpGkoqaboKOnkaWpa1/7PTczM0wDq1ABxAA)

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOi2/SCPP1sBaWztP19DA0DpP39BA10hNLU8VQhcUZeaVpGkoqaboKOnkaWpa1/7PTczM0wDq1ABxAA).

Comment: @JonathanFrech thanks that's clever!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>53 51 50 49</s> 46 bytes

```python
['2'in str(n)or print(n)for n in range(1,101)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1rdSD0zT6G4pEgjTzO/SKGgKDOvBMhMA7LzFIAyRYl56akahjqGBoaasf//AwA)

Not the strongest language for this task, but I'm new to golfing.

Thanks to the commenters for their tips!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can get it down to a round 50 by deleting the space before the `if`.

Comment: `[print(n)for n in range(1,101)if"2"not in str(n)]` works.

Comment: Alternatively, based on one of the Python 2 answers: `n=17;exec("print((n>177)*10+n//9);n+=10;"*81)`

Comment: @JosiahRyanW I wasn't aware of the implicit print, thanks!

Comment: It's not really "implicit printing", but rather a print statement inside a list comprehension. You still need the `print` statement.

Comment: @JosiahRyanW I misread your comment and saved just the list comprehension `[print(n)for n in range(1,101)if"2"not in str(n)]` as a one-line file, and it output the desired results when I ran it. That's what I thought was implicit printing.

Comment: @Gigaflop Ah, I get it. Still, I do find it cool that they're able to do that.

Comment: `'2'in str(n)or print(n)` is shorter than a comprehension guard.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

## sh + coreutils, 16 chars

```
seq 100|sed /2/d
```

Generates sequence from 1 to 100 (inclusive) and deletes any lines that have '2' in them.

Comment: This code is identical to [answer by Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173262/11157).

Comment: oh crap, didn't see that one, even though I checked. Should I delete this since mine was posted later?

Answer (score 4):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```
00000000: 1630 2e0a 5faf f57b fe02 2818 82ff f182  .0.._..{..(.....
00000010: ff92 3cf5 7dff f1bd 280a fe02 2803 f518  ..<.}...(...(...
00000020: e63c 18fa 7b3c bd20 db3e 31ff 3dff ff76  .<..{<. .>1.=..v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc6xDsIwDATQna@4sdPJcdQ2oMKvoKaJWZDYGEB8ezBtJW6yrPOTX0luj7u1JntOCEMUaJUZvc0G68cMq6LQFBKSmu9CUoBCXsk32fGXwyYEN8yOirhYj7Gs/Vz83MkdkuiuayAnfrgJ3d9QN@oQF4RkM8bsUy4qKDlWxOBkXF0bBzcmf2IieAk8k8/Wvg)

Assembly:

```
ld d, 30h			; ascii '0' character
ld l, 0Ah			; number 10 and ascii newline
tens:
	ld e,a			; store tens digit
	xor a			; reset ones digit to 0
	push af			; store initial ones digit 0
	ones:
		ld a,e		; get stored tens digit
		cp 2
		jr z,cont	; if tens digit==2(e.g.20-29),skip loop
		add d
		rst 38h 	; print tens digit
		pop af		; get stored ones digit
		add d
		rst 38h 	; print ones digit
		sub d
		inc a		; increment ones digit
		push af		; store ones digit
		ld a, l
		rst 38h 	; print newline
		pop af		; get stored ones digit again
		cp l
		jr z,cont	; if ones digit==10, break loop
		cp 2
		jr z,inc_again	; if ones digit==2, incr again
		repeat_loop:
		push af		; store ones digit again
		jr ones		; repeat print loop
		inc_again:
			inc a
			jr repeat_loop
		
	cont:
	ld a,e			; get stored tens digit
	inc a			; increment tens digit
	cp l
	jr nz, tens		; if tens place!=10, continue loop
ld a,31h
rst 38h				; print '1'
dec a
rst 38h				; print '0'
rst 38h				; print '0'
halt
```

Saved one byte with the `repeat_loop` jump

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 32 bytes

```
{(1..100).filter{'2' !in ""+it}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsIwEEbhfU/x200niKF1WWrApeDOE2RhymAcSzoKEnL2WN/@e4@XRpYa3oKnZyGf5nXEOSX/nW6aWGZnkBtsfXxEGEEGB4crrzpdRB1ONdNg7dD3xgaOek@5O3bYsaBt96yl1L9etpdSIGOaUn8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 31 bytes

```bash
printf %d\\n {1..100}|grep -v 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUE1JSYmT6HaUE/P0MCgtia9KLVAQbdMwej/fwA)

Thanks to Digital Trauma for short loop.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!  How about `echo $i` instead of the printf?  Or even better `printf %d\\n {1..100}|grep -v 2`?

Comment: yeah right. i ll update my answer.

Comment: i am learning actually i don't know that much btw thanks.

Comment: Just beats my `echo {1..100}|tr ' ' \\n|grep -v 2`

Comment: -1 byte if you use `sed /2/d` instead of `grep -v 2`.

Comment: The entire `printf` can be replaced with `seq 100`, which delimits with newlines by default.

Answer (score 3):

## [ORK](https://github.com/TryItOnline/ork), 1092 bytes

```
There is such a thing as a t
A t can w a number
A t can d a number
A t has a t which is a number

When a t is to w a number:
I have a mathematician called M
M's first operand is the number
M's second operand is 1
M is to add
The number is M's result
My t is 0
I have a number called n
n is the number
I am to d n
M's first operand is my t
M's second operand is 1
M is to compare
I have a scribe called W
If M says it's less then W is to write the number
If M says it's less then W is to write " "
M's first operand is the number
M's second operand is 100
M is to compare
If M says it's less then I am to loop

When a t is to d a number:
I have a mathematician called M
M's first operand is the number
M's second operand is 10
M is to modulo
I have a mathematician called N
N's first operand is M's result
N's second operand is 2
N is to compare
If N says it's equal then my t is 1
M is to divide
The number is M's result
M's first operand is the number
M's second operand is 0
M is to compare
If M says it's greater then I am to loop

When this program starts:
I have a t called T
T is to w 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVM9b8IwEN39K04sXdOO3ToyJFMkZmMf2Ko/Up8D4tenF0hIKFAqpC5Rcs/33su7c0yfXVcbTAiWgFplQEI2NmxBUv8qPiCDkgH2/BVav8Z0LunLkjl1wN5YprE0oWJlMBwxruY443oXS@7bIRe8zAb5YZVlbiWdQw2lKF8INjZRhthgkkEfOQyO3D1OqCIDswOvohy0pNaiPh/vi31HQmpdFuXh5KmYbAznBv0gwg@9JUjf8/bYTW@eOR@6UtE3MuEkSyrZNY6yK7HcQAkkDwQ2M5dDOroIsBozTDbjhbG/dSxg8WymRXHt/57oGJOLsbmav/7/@U9WfdStiw90KlHd0pmtSnVT501U14lUs0Twq5XuFIkflm3aAm13VuMv6/nUvz@c0jahzCx2b1B8/wmaFLeJIcoyZZrNKY@Z1aI@3@ei674B)

**O**bjects **R** **K**ool. Output is a space-delimited list of numbers.

This translates (approximately) to the following pseudocode:

```
class t {
	int t;
	
	void w(number) {
		label T_W;
		mathematician M;
		M.first_operand = number;
		M.second_operand = 1;
		M.add();
		number = M.result;
		t = 0;
		int n = number;
		d(n);
		M.first_operand = t;
		M.second_operand = 1;
		M.compare();
		scribe W;
		if M.its_less { W.write(number); }
		if M.its_less { W.write(" "); }
		M.first_operand = number;
		M.second_operand = 100;
		M.compare();
		if M.its_less { goto T_W; }
	}
	
	void d(number) {
		label T_D;
		mathematician M;
		M.first_operand = number;
		M.second_operand = 10;
		M.modulo();
		mathematician N;
		N.first_operand = M.result;
		N.second_operand = 2;
		N.compare();
		if N.its_equal { t = 1; }
		M.divide();
		number = M.result;
		M.first_operand = number;
		M.second_operand = 0;
		M.compare();
		if M.its_greater { goto T_D; }
	}
}

void main() {
	t T;
	T.w(0);
}
```

As you can see, *everything* is done using objects, including basic math and IO functions (through the built-in mathematician and scribe classes). Only whole functions can loop, which explains the need for an object with two functions to do the work.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP 7.1, 40 bytes

```php
while($i++<100)strstr($i,50)||print$i._;
```

prints numbers separated by underscores. Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21335cb48b903f157762c893119666dc11c43d15).

Comment: Nice use of PHP's wacky behavior to separate the numbers, lol

Comment: The `preg_filter()` based one is interesting. (I never used that function. ) That one would be shorter with `preg_grep()`: `<?=join(_,preg_grep("/2/",range(1,100),1));`.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
♀╒Ç{2╧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RzIZHUycdbq82ejR1@f//AA)

### Explanation

```
♀╒       Push 100 and convert to 1-based range ([1,2,...,100])
  Č{     Inverse filter by block
    2╧   Does the number contain 2?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 56 bytes

```c
f(i){for(i=0;i++<100;i%10^2&&i/10^2&&printf("%d\n",i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P00jU7M6Lb9II9PWwDpTW9vG0ABIqxoaxBmpqWXqQ@iCosy8kjQNJdWUmDwlnUxNTeva/0ARhdzEzDwNoHYNTeui1JLSojwFA6AMAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 44 bytes

```
repeat n 100[unless find form n"2"[print n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@78otSA1sUQhT8HQwCC6NC8ntbhYIS0zL0UhLb8oVyFPyUgpuqAoMw@oIjb2/38A)

Uses `unless` instead of `if not`, because why not? :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <strike>35</strike> 31 bytes

```ruby
100.times{|e|p e if/2/!~e.to_s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfavtf167a0MBAryQzN7W4uia1pkAhVSEzTd9IX7EuVa8kP764tvZ/anTsfwA)

Thanks to [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien) for -4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 176 bytes

```
---------[[-<]-[>]>[>]-[-<]<++]-[>-<+++++++++]>--[>[->]<[<<<]>>[->]>-]<<,<-[-<]>[>]<[.[->+<]++++++++++.,<]>>[>]>>->-<<<<[>>>[<<[<]<.>>[>]>.[-<+>]++++++++++.,>]<<[<]<,<]>>>>.<..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1bCsRQCEMXZHUFIRsRP9qBgTIwH4Wu/zbXeUAD4itHt2Pd38/z8RrDf8p0lCeLCp8NzObAlb8qysd0FhJAsWt6AQuamTAyNDbUn7NY2iwvXQelpHolvYnPRhCMN0i32tE0GYgY4wI)

Shorter is definitely possible. This generates the numbers `1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` and `0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. First it outputs each number in the first list, then it outputs every combination of the first and second list, then finally prints just `100`.

#### Explanation:

```
---------   Push minus 9
[           Repeat 9 times
  [-<]-[>]    Add the negative of the number to the first list
  >[>]-[-<]<  Add the negative of the number to the second list
  ++          Increment the counter
]
Tape: 255 254 253 252 251 250 249 248 247 0' 0 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254
-[>-<+++++++++]>--  Push 197
Tape: 255 254 253 252 251 250 249 248 247 0 197' 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254
[
  >[->]<    Subtract 197 from every element in both lists to convert to digits
  [<<<]>>
  [->]>-
]
Tape: 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 49 0' 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57
<<,<-[-<]>[>]<  Remove the 0 and the 2 from the first list
Tape: 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 0 0 0' 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57
[  Loop over the first list
  .[->+<]        Print digit
  ++++++++++.,<  Print a newline
]
>>[>]>>->-   Remove the 2 from the second list
<<<<      
[  Loop over first list
  >>>
  [  Loop over second list
    <<[<]<.        Print first digit
    >>[>]>.        Print second digit
    [-<+>]         Move second digit over one
    ++++++++++.,>  Print a newline
  ]
  <<[<]<,<  Remove the digit from the first list and move to the next
]
>>>>.<..  Print 100 using the second list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 51 bytes

This was a fun challenge!
And it is a challenge where my language can do well.

```
{@forfrom 1to100}{@if_ is notmatches"<2>"}{@echol_}
```

Cycles through all values from 1 to 100, outputting the ones that don't have 2, separated by a newline.

You can try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c97a2b6954c29844f1079938da771d51e2e0d99

**Ungolfed:**

```
{@for i from 1 to 100}
    {@if i is not matches "<2>"}
        {@echo i, "\n"}
    {@/}
{@/}
```

The `{@/}` is used to close the `{@for ...}` and `{@if ...}`, but is optional.
When compiling to PHP, it adds the needed closing.

---

If you're curious, the golfed code results in this PHP code:

```
// {@forfrom 1to100}
// ~ optimization enabled ~ inlining the results
foreach(array(...) as $DATA['_']){

    // {@if_ is notmatches"<2>"}
    if(!(preg_match("<2>", (isset($DATA['_'])?$DATA['_']:null)))) {

        // {@echol_}
        echo implode('', $FN['array_flat']((isset($DATA['_'])?$DATA['_']:null)));echo PHP_EOL;


// AUTO-CLOSE
};};
```

Where `$FN['array_flat']` is defined outside of this code.

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download), 15 bytes

**Solution:**

```
1_&~"2"in'$!101
```

**Example:**

```
q)k)1_&~"2"in'$!101
1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 30 31 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

**Explanation:**

```
1_&~"2"in'$!101 / the solution
           !101 / range 0..100
          $     / string
    "2"in'      / is "2" in each?
   ~            / not
  &             / indices where true
1_              / drop the first
```

**Extra:**

TIO for **16 byte** [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok) answer: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/3zBerS4zL9rUIFZdRdHQwPD/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
³D2eṆƲƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QZhej1Ic7245tOtb@/z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

```
VS100I!}\2%"%s"NN
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyzY0MDAU7E2xkhVSbVYyc/v/38A)

My first code golf submission, also my first time using Pyth, this took way longer to put together than I expected.

## Explanation

`VS100` **for** loop from 1 to 100

`I!}\2%"%s` **if** the string "2" is in the string conversion of N

`%"%sN` **convert N to a string.** This is the only way I could figure out how to do this. If there is a shorter way to do int -> string conversion please let me know. I'm honestly just looking for a way to call str() or repr() on it with less chars.

`N` **print n**

EDIT: Looks like someone else beat me to it with Pyth. Turns out to convert N to a str I could do `N`, I'm going to leave mine the same because if I change it its almost the exact same solution.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, <s>56</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```
1 to'd'filter(_+""forall(50!=))map println
```

Prints the elements separated by a line.

Here is a 38 bytes version that calls `toString` (technically allowed by the rules):

```
print(1 to'd'filter(_+""forall(50!=)))
```

Resulting in:

```
Vector(1, 3, 4, ..., 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 19 bytes

```perl
map{/2/||say}1..100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqmCqZ2BoYP0/N7GgWt9Iv6amOLGy1lBPz9DA4P9/AA)

Comment: Nice, can't come to with anything more terse just yet! You can save one bute going with `map/2/||say,1..100` though!

Answer (score 2):

## [Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 32 bytes

```
END{while(i++<100)print i~2?a:i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@lujwjMydVI1Nb28bQwECzoCgzr0Qhs87IPtEqs/b/fwA)

To save space, I used Awk's behavior of assigning the null string to uninitialized variables to avoid initializing the counter and saving a byte with the null string literal.

Answer (score 2):

## Uiua, 36 bytes

Returns an array with numbers from 1 to 100 where the elements containing a two are removed.

```
▽×∩(≠2)⌊⊃÷◿10.+1⇡100
```

[Try It](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4pa9w5fiiKko4omgMinijIriioPDt-KXvzEwLisx4oehMTAwCg==)

```
▽×∩(≠2)⌊⊃÷◿10.+1⇡100
              +1⇡100 # generate numbers 1..100
             . # duplicate the array for filtering
        ⊃÷◿10 # both divide by 10 and mod 10 each number
       ⌊ # floor the division result so that we have the 10s place
  ∩(≠2) # for both the mod and floored division (ones and tens places)
        # check that there is no 2
 × # use multiply as and
▽ # filter the array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
2N_FN\,h
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbo5S7IKlpSVpuhYrjPzi3fxidDIgXKjoAigNAA)

#### Explanation

```
       h  Preset variable: 100
     \,   1-based range: [1 2 3 ... 100]
   FN     Filter Negated on this function (i.e. keep falsey results):
2N_        Number of 2s iN the argument
          Print the resulting list (newline-separated thanks to -l flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 51 bytes

After reading [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173204/16766), I wanted to try a non-recursive approach. Sure enough, it's longer, but it may be of some interest.

```javascript
_=>[...Array(101).keys()].filter(n=>n*!/2/.test(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAt3Rbg7bsrtA7IkJsDUvWUAl8vTXHucxrsk3@KQPHg5pTbVd6RcQlJVNBTlLgTTWD2ND5UCgBK819N84jFsoFWIhmI@cYCEM8wcEfHw)

`[...Array(101).keys()]` creates a list of the numbers 0 through 100. We then `filter` to get rid of 0 and any number that contains a 2.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 121 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   T   S S T   S T N
_Push_101][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_EXIT][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T S T T   _Modulo][S S S T    S N
_Push_2][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T S T S _Integer_divide][S S S T  S N
_Push_2][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
S T _Print_integer_to_STDOUT][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T N
S S _Print_character_to_STDOUT][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYsLiIE0JxenggKEqcAJZHJCRMAEF1QYCIFckCyEBZZFk1TAkOTkUuCEKwDbxsX1/z8A) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Pseudo-code:**

```
Integer i = 0
Label LOOP:
  i = i+1
  If(i == 101):
    Exit program
  If(i modulo-10 == 2):
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
  If(i integer-divided by 10 == 2):
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
  Print i to STDOUT
  Print a newline to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 17 chars, 34 bytes

```
a/⍨∼'2'∊¨⍕¨a←⍳100
```

test

```
  a/⍨∼'2'∊¨⍕¨a←⍳100
1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 30 31 33 
  34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
  51 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 63 64 65 66 67 68 
  69 70 71 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 83 84 85 86 
  87 88 89 90 91 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Comment: I don't know much about APL (much less this specific variant), but aren't the instructions typically single bytes from a different codepage?

Comment: @Joking in this case 'codepage' is 2 bytes for one char

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 19 bytes

```
`dFLP:aSD2=$2=+ZN|;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/PyHFzSfAKjHYxchWxchWO8qvxvr/fwA)

Explanation:

```
`dFLP:aSD2=$2=+ZN|;

`d                  //Push 100 to the stack
  F                 //For loop from 0 to 99
   LP               //  Push the loopcounter+1 to the stack,achieving a range [1..100]
     :              //  Double for potential output later (saves 1 byte compared to pushing it again)
      aSD           //  Push division & modulus of current number by 10
         2=         //  Check if (num % 10) == 2 , pushes either 0 or 1
           $2=      //  Check if (num / 10) == 2 , "
              +     //  Add the results acting as a logical or for is zero question
               ZN   //  If neither the mod nor the div are equal to 2 output the number
                 |; //Exit after loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 28 characters

```ruby
puts [*?1..'100'].grep_v /2/
```

Thanks to:

- [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b), as I borrowed the idea of not using a proc from his [deleted answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173284)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ ruby -e 'puts [*?1.."100"].grep_v /2/' | head -15
1
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
13
14
15
16
17
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFghWsveUE9P3dDAQD1WL70otSC@TEHfSP//fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @oktupol*

```
á199ñÄj<C-a>ñç2/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BCQ0vLwxsPt2TZOOsm2gFZy430U/7//69bBgA) `<C-A>` represents the start of heading character (`0x01`)

### Explanation

```
á1            Insert a 1 on the first line
99ñ           Repeat 99 times:
 Ä             Duplicate the last line
 j<C-A>        Increment the last line by one
ñç2/          For every line containing a 2:
 d             Remove the line
```

Comment: Use [globals](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/wiki/Regexes#global) to save one byte: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K/v///BCQ0vLwxsPt2TZOOsm2gFZy430U/7//69bBgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 58 bytes

```forth
: f 101 1 do i 10 /mod 2 <> swap 2 <> * if i . then loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRgaGCoYKqTkK2QCmQr6ufkpCkYKNnYKxeWJBRCWlkJmGlBWT6EkIzVPISc/v0DB@n/afwA)

#### Explanation

Loops from 1 to 100 (inclusive) and if both the ones and tens place of the index are not equal to 2, print it

#### Code explanation

```forth
: f                    \ start a new word definition
  101 1 do             \ start a loop from 1 to 100 inclusive
    i 10 /mod          \ get the quotient and remainder of dividing i by 10
    2 <>               \ check if the the tens place is not equal to 2
    swap               \ move the result down the stack one
    2 <>               \ check that the ones place is not equal to 2
    *                  \ multiply results (cheaper AND)
    if i . then        \ if true, output i
  loop                 \ end counted loop
;                      \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
f!}`2`TS100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P02xNsEoISTY0MDg/38A)

-2 with many thanks (nearly a year later!) to @ar4093

Original version:

```
VS*TTI!}\2`NN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyxYKyTEU7E2xijBz@//fwA)

I'm still a Pyth beginner so this could probably be improved on.

**Explanation**

```
for N in num_to_range(Psorted(times(T,T))):   # For N in range 1 to 10*10
 if Pnot(Pin("2",repr(N))):                   # If "2" is not in `N`
  imp_print(N)                                # Print N
```

Comment: -2 bytes by using filtering instead of a for loop: `f!}\`2\`TS100`

Answer (score 1):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 59 bytes

```
1 FOR I=1 TO 100:IF INSTR(STR$(I),"2")=0 THEN PRINT I
2 NEXT
```

There's probably a mathematical way to do this, but this approach is what first came to mind.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 65 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=1a:IF @ NOT LIKE'%2%'PRINT @;SET @+=1IF @<101GOTO a
```

I'm a bit annoyed that this variable loop is shorter than the best set-based SQL variant I could find (**91 bytes**):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT number FROM spt_values WHERE number>0and number<101AND number NOT LIKE'%2%'
```

This one even has the additional restriction of needing to be run in the `master` database (since it uses an undocumented system table).

The best set-based solution I could find without that requirement was **94 bytes**:

```sql
WITH t AS(SELECT 1n UNION ALL SELECT n+1FROM t WHERE n<100)SELECT*FROM t WHERE n NOT LIKE'%2%'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (5.12+), 25 bytes

```perl
$,=$/;say grep!/2/,1..100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqmCqZ2BoZP1fRcdWRd@6OLFSIb0otUBR30hfx1BPz9DA4P9/AA)

Pretty straightforward. The `$,=$/` makes the following print put a newline between list elements, which is shorter than using `join`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 24 bytes

```
Output!2&`!in@List\1:100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/37@0pKC0RNFILUExM8/BJ7O4JMbQytDA4P9/AA)

Alternatively, `` Print=>2&`!in@List\1:100 ``.

Filters (`\`) from `1:100` values whose digits (`@List`) do not contain (`` `!in ``) a 2 (`2&`), which is then `Output`ted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
p$.if"#{$.+=1}"!~/2/ until$.>99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BFLzNNSblaRU/b1rBWSbFO30hfoTwjMydVRc/G0MDgv7KCiUWSlYKGgZ4ekKupl5qYnFFdk1pToJCqkJmmoBidqm9ooAMigGSsXmZeSmqFglEtF1CfAVAf2HwNsOmaeiX58cW2dfpx0XFGsdoqKPYA1RtbwNQj3INHtSlMtYKiBooGI31NNKVGmAZjehQA)

A different, iterative approach than other ruby answers. This uses the not-match operator `!~` as well as the implicitly-zero input line number variable `$.` as the iterator. The TIO link shows my golfing progress, from 48 bytes to 31 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 66 bytes

### Solution

```
Seq.filter(fun i->i%10<>2&&i/10<>2){1..100}|>Seq.iter(printfn"%d")
```

### Explanation

Filters a sequence of numbers 1 to 100 by retaining those whose modulus of 10 is not 2, and which integer-divided by 10 do not result in 2, then prints the sequence with newlines between items.

This works for numbers up to and including 199. A more general solution is slightly longer (74 bytes):

```
Seq.filter(fun i->(string i).IndexOf '2'<0){1..100}|>Seq.iter(printfn"%d")
```

With proper spacing, and rearranged for readability, this looks as follows:

```
{1 .. 100}
|> Seq.filter (fun i -> (string i).IndexOf '2' < 0)
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)], <s>63</s> 62 bytes

Thanks to [milk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58106/milk) for saving one byte in the for loop.

```cs
for(int i=0;++i<101;)if(i%10!=2&&i/10!=2)Console.WriteLine(i);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcaxCsIwEAbgVzkHS0JRE9fYybVODs4hXuWHmkDuFErps0fwm74kh1Qqt48gv@i@iPI7pDmKUFxFoyLRt@BJt4hs7NqmUg2yEgYX@h4X73ywmAz23u2Gc9fh9I@9lixl5uOjQnlEZgMb2ra1Hw)

Ungolfed:

```cs
for (int i = 0; ++i < 101;)         // all integers from 1-100 (starts from zero, increments before code runs)
    if (i % 10 != 2                 // all numbers not ending with '2'
                    && i / 10 != 2) // all numbers not starting with '2'
        Console.WriteLine(i);       // write to console
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using this pattern for the for loop: `for(int i=0;++i<101;)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 65 bytes

```rust
fn main(){for i in 1..101{if i%10!=2&&i/10!=2{println!("{}",i)}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Dszotv0ghUyEzT8FQT8/QwLA6M00hU9XQQNHWSE0tUx/MqC4oyswryclT1FCqrlXSydSsra39/x8A)

Similar to the answers by [Meerkat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173375/75118) and [dumetrulo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173338/75118), just iterate through and print only those whose ones digit and tens digit are not 2.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 7 <strike>9</strike> bytes

```
⁸#u⁇2εX
```

Explanation:

```
⁸#u⁇2εX
⁸        Push 100
 #       Push range 0..a
  u      Turn to string (vectorizes)
   ⁇     Filter only those that match conditional
    2εX  Match those that do not contain "2"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//1HjDuXSR43tSkZK57ZG/P8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [LUA](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/), <strike>113</strike> <strike>68</strike> <strike>47</strike> 45 bytes

Thanks to LUA's rather loose dynamic typing, can straight-up search the integer.

Thanks to *@manatwork* (twice)

Thanks to *@Jo King*

```
for x=1,100 do n=("").find(x,2)or print(x)end
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/repls/PrestigiousVacantTrial)

Comment: “All solutions to challenges should: (…) Be a serious contender for the winning criteria in use. For example, an entry to a code golf contest needs to be golfed, and an entry to a speed contest should make some attempt to be fast.” — [help/on-topic] Please try to reduce the size of your solution. With just minimal refactoring can become 68 characters long: `x=0 while x<100 do x=x+1 if not string.find(x,2)then print(x)end end`. There are some [Tips for golfing in Lua](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24392/tips-for-golfing-in-lua) to help you out.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can golf this down to [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IocLWUMfQwEAhJV8hz7a4pCgzL10vLTMvRaNCx0gTKF8AFCnRqNBMzUv5/x8A) using a for loop and a ternary statement instead of an `if`

Comment: Thanks. Still trolling through that tips link to see what can apply. Tried a few things, but the online compiler didn't seem to like my attempts at brevity. There are obviously many answers here posted that were not going to be a contender (the C# is my favorite, but I like the Taxi answer as well).

Comment: Ah, most people consider code-golf a competition between submissions in the same language. While a Taxi or Shakespeare submission might appear absurdly long compared to regular programming languages, remember that *they* are far outgolfed by any highly focused golfing language. Hope you stick around, since there aren't that many Lua golfers :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Still wondering if there isn't some way curb this even more using a goto statement. Now taking a look at your 47 byte solution...

Comment: 45 if you call the method on a string literal: `("").find(x,2)`

Comment: @manatwork, That's a nice trick. Feeling very humbled now....

Answer (score 1):

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org), 65 bytes

```ruby
(1..100).each do |x|
    x.to_s().includes?('2') ? 0 : puts x
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcFBCoAgEAXQvaf4O3UzaMs2HiVEhQLRaBQMvLv1Xnhebj6vpSyRNUZT8uFErJgYmAK/Qa0erDRdJeQeEzslN6nhYLDj7o0xRCpxrQ8)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can golf this down to 49 bytes by removing some whitespace, and using the fact that `do...end` can be replaced by `{...}`: `(1..100).each{|x|x.to_s.includes?('2')?0: puts x}` If you use `p x` instead of `puts x` you can shave some more bytes

Comment: Im newer to crystal. So thanks, I didn't even know all that stuff!

Comment: @Dylan I would suggest to incorporate said golfing suggestions to improve your score.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tidy](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Tidy), 27 bytes

```
{{x:"2"!in x.0}from[1,100]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8lMqfyfpmBl@7@6usJKyUhJMTNPoULPoDatKD832lDH0MAgtvZ/cUZ@uUaahqbmfwA)

Function which returns the appropriate range. `x.0` concatenates `x` and `0` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>45</strike> 44 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)

```javascript
for(i=0;i++<100;)/2/.test(i)||console.log(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9II9PWwDpTW9vG0MDAWlPfSF@vJLW4RCNTs6YmOT@vOD8nVS8nPx3I//8fAA)

Comment: Can you not use `||` instead of `?0:`?

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Batch, <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```
@for /l %%G in (1,1,100)do @echo %%G|find /v "2"
```

Loops from 1 to 100, and for each number looped, only output those who does not contain any "2".

1 byte is saved by @Neil.

Comment: You don't need that `~` do you?

Comment: Oh! You're right. It looks like I have forgotten how to code golf.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 57 Bytes

**Solution**

```
import Data.List
unlines.nub.map(filter(/='2').show).$[1..100]
```

or

```
import Data.List
nub.map(filter(/='2').show)$[1..100]
```

if you just want the list.

**Output**

```
Prelude Data.List> unlines.nub.map(filter(/='2').show)$[1..]
"1\n\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n0\n30\n31\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n41\n43\n44\n45\n46\n47\n48\n49\n50\n51\n53\n54\n55\n56\n57\n58\n59\n60\n61\n63\n64\n65\n66\n67\n68\n69\n70\n71\n73\n74\n75\n76\n77\n78\n79\n80\n81\n83\n84\n85\n86\n87\n88\n89\n90\n91\n93\n94\n95\n96\n97\n98\n99\n100
```

**Explanation**

Makes all numbers a string, removes their '2's and weeds out the duplicates.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. We usually add all necessary `imports` to the byte count, here `import Data.List`. However, you can declare that your program is not written in plain `Haskell`, but in some variant that includes stuff by default, e.g. `Haskell (lambdabot)`.

Comment: Additionally to what @nimi mentioned, your answer is not valid because your program lists values over *100* too, it will print two newlines after `1` and a `0` after `19`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 33 bytes

#### Solution:

```
puts (?1..'100').reject{|x|x[?2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 57 bytes

```
_=>`${[...Array(101).keys()]}`.replace(/^0,|\d?2.?,/g,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHtCkAwFADQl1Hurbk@/iPP4XPNJSzTJiU8@5yzyks6ZZfjjHYzsp9y3@fFEDw1EVXWyhvSJEXa@HaA7TeQ5UNLxRB3iXibscyoFPEswhC9MrszmkmbGSZA9D8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
₁'2c¬
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoEnMmPCrCIsIiIsIiJd)

#### Explained

```
₁'2c¬
₁     # push 100 to stack
 '    # filter lambda
  2c  # contains 2
    ¬ # logical NOT
```

Comment: use the `H` flag to set the stack to 100... :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$9\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 7.408 bytes

```
Fa@2'r-2f
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJGYUAyJ3ItMmYiLCIiXQ==)

-1 or something thanks to Seggan

```
F         # Filter 
 a@2      # range(1, 100)
    '     # by...
      -2  # Subtracting 2 from
        f # each digit
     r    # Are all truthy?
```

Comment: Use `@2` for `100`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `Rj`, 4 bytes

```
₅ᶻ2c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJSaiIsIiIsIuKCheG2uzJjIiwiIiwiIiwiMy40LjEiXQ==)

rip -H flag

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
Lh2N Ui|Pi
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuharfDKM_BRCM2sCMiECUHGYPAA)

#### Explanation

Flagless version, inspired by [Xcali's Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190551/16766).

```
            i is preinitialized to 0
Lh          Loop 100 times:
     Ui      Increment i
  2N         Count occurrences of 2 in (the new value of) i
       |     If that is falsey (0), then
        Pi   Print i
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 50 bytes

```
@L
N=N+1IF.>INSTR(STR$(N),"2")THEN?N
ON N>99GOTO@L
```

#### Explanation:

```
@LABEL
 N = N + 1
 IF 0 > INSTR(STR$(N), "2") THEN PRINT N
ON N>99 GOTO @LABEL
```

`INSTR(STR$(N), "2")` is -1 if `N` doesn't contain a 2.

`ON ... GOTO` takes a list of labels, and jumps to a label in that list corresponding to the value of an expression.
If N isn't greater than 99, `N>99` returns 0 so it jumps to the 0th label, `@LABEL`.
Otherwise, `N>99` is 1 so it tries to jump to label 1 in the list, but since the list isn't long enough, it doesn't jump and the program ends.

`ON` is meant to be used like `switch`/`case`, with a longer list of labels. But `ON x GOTO @LABEL` can be used as a shorter way of writing `IF !(x) GOTO @LABEL`:

```
IF N<=99GOTO@L
IF N<100GOTO@L
ON N>99GOTO@L
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 34 bytes

```
-(i){("{i}"!?"2"):{i}}
{i<100:->i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v9fVyNTs1pDqTqzVknRXslISdMKyKzlqs60MTQwsNK1y6z9/x8A)

#### Explanation

```
-(i)             // Labelled gather - keeps track of how many times it's been visited (in variable i)
{"{i}"!?"2":     // If "2" is not a substring of i...
{i}              // ...print i
}
{i<100:->i}      // If i is less than 100, go back to i.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 18 bytes/keystrokes

```
100o0<esc>V{g<C-a>J:g/2/d<cr>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39DAIN/AJrU42S6sOt3GWTfRzssqXd9IP4Xr////umUA)

Answer (score 0):

### C++, <s>84</s> 81 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

The function needs a void return value to compile with MSVC

```cpp
#include<cstdio>
void f(){for(int i=0;++i<101;)i%10-2&&i/10-2&&printf("%d\n",i);}
```

The `if` read as "if the first digit isn't 2 and the second digit isn't 2"

Answer (score 0):

## Deadfish~

```
{iiiii}dc{dddd}ic{iiii}ic{dddd}dc{iiii}iic{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiic{dddd}dddc{iiii}iiiic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}iiiiic{dddd}dddddc{iiii}iiiiiic{dddd}ddddddc{iiiii}dddc{ddddd}iiic{iiii}dcdc{dddd}iic{iiii}dcc{dddd}ic{iiii}dciic{dddd}dc{iiii}dciiic{dddd}ddc{iiii}dciiiic{dddd}dddc{iiii}dciiiiic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}dciiiiiic{dddd}dddddc{iiii}dc{i}dddc{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}dc{i}ddc{ddddd}iiic{iiii}icdddc{dddd}iic{iiii}icddc{dddd}ic{iiii}icc{dddd}dc{iiii}icic{dddd}ddc{iiii}iciic{dddd}dddc{iiii}iciiic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}iciiiic{dddd}dddddc{iiii}iciiiiic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}iciiiiiic{ddddd}iiic{iiii}iicddddc{dddd}iic{iiii}iicdddc{dddd}ic{iiii}iicdc{dddd}dc{iiii}iicc{dddd}ddc{iiii}iicic{dddd}dddc{iiii}iiciic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}iiciiic{dddd}dddddc{iiii}iiciiiic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}iiciiiiic{ddddd}iiic{iiii}iiicdddddc{dddd}iic{iiii}iiicddddc{dddd}ic{iiii}iiicddc{dddd}dc{iiii}iiicdc{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiicc{dddd}dddc{iiii}iiicic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}iiiciic{dddd}dddddc{iiii}iiiciiic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}iiiciiiic{ddddd}iiic{iiii}iiiicddddddc{dddd}iic{iiii}iiiicdddddc{dddd}ic{iiii}iiiicdddc{dddd}dc{iiii}iiiicddc{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiiicdc{dddd}dddc{iiii}iiiicc{dddd}ddddc{iiii}iiiicic{dddd}dddddc{iiii}iiiiciic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}iiiiciiic{ddddd}iiic{iiii}iiiiic{d}iiic{dddd}iic{iiii}iiiiicddddddc{dddd}ic{iiii}iiiiicddddc{dddd}dc{iiii}iiiiicdddc{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiiiicddc{dddd}dddc{iiii}iiiiicdc{dddd}ddddc{iiii}iiiiicc{dddd}dddddc{iiii}iiiiicic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}iiiiiciic{ddddd}iiic{iiii}iiiiiic{d}iic{dddd}iic{iiii}iiiiiic{d}iiic{dddd}ic{iiii}iiiiiicdddddc{dddd}dc{iiii}iiiiiicddddc{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiiiiicdddc{dddd}dddc{iiii}iiiiiicddc{dddd}ddddc{iiii}iiiiiicdc{dddd}dddddc{iiii}iiiiiicc{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}iiiiiicic{ddddd}iiic{iiiii}dddc{d}ic{dddd}iic{iiiii}dddc{d}iic{dddd}ic{iiiii}dddcddddddc{dddd}dc{iiiii}dddcdddddc{dddd}ddc{iiiii}dddcddddc{dddd}dddc{iiiii}dddcdddc{dddd}ddddc{iiiii}dddcddc{dddd}dddddc{iiiii}dddcdc{dddd}ddddddc{iiiii}dddcc{ddddd}iiic{iiii}dcdcc
```